# Why do newbie questions bring so many reputation points to the author?

Tags: discussion, questions, reputation

I not surprised to see basic questions like "How to get length of a string in Python...?". Even people can easily find the answer inside the documentation, and it's pretty straightforward for other people googling the question to have the question/answer on Stack Overflow.
As a consequence, since it helps lots of users, there are lots of +1 on these questions.

+1 on these questions give reputation points to the author.

Is it really fair to give so many reputation points to someone that just didn't read the documentation and asked this kind of question (even the question itself is useful)?

Comment: Cross-site dupe of [Life isn't fair](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/202652)

Comment: I always sort of assumed it was people who answered the question upvoting it in the hopes that a positive score would attract more people to the question who would then upvote their answer. But perhaps I'm reading into it too much. That only applies to new questions, though. The old ones just have a lot of votes because they were useful to a lot of people.

Comment: I think you're right. But when a question is upvoted 400 times, then it's can't be true anymore :)

Comment: Well, a lot of people need to know how to get the length of a string in Python. These people google it, SO is the first result, they go to the question and upvote. This happens for years. 400 upvotes on a common question is normal. :) It's only annoying when people post dupes which then get upvoted for the reasons I suggested above.

Comment: The more trivial the question, the more likely that SO users will recognize a correct answer, the more likely they'll vote for it.  Answering a trivial question and still getting SO users to appreciate the answer isn't that simple btw, you do have to tell a pretty good story.

Comment: If it's upvoted 400 times, then it's likely an old/legacy question that was asked when stack overflow was a lot less mature than it is now. A similar question today would likely get a different response because it would already have an answer. The original poster simply got their first and has therefore documented the answer for future users as a reference.

Comment: @Tanner: If the language is new, it's still OK to ask these questions thought. OK I admit there isn't a new language every day :)

Comment: I don't see why not. If the language is completely new, then it's fair game as long as the question is answerable and it broadly meets the posting guidelines.

Comment: @Tanner Finding the length of a string in Python would have been well documented before SO even existed.  That question was not actually adding value to the repository of knowledge on the internet.  The question would only ever be drawing traffic away from some other source, such as the documentation.

Comment: @DavidW. show us the link for that question. we can better flag that question

Answer (score 19):

First, questions by new users are sometimes upvoted more than if a greater-than-200-rep more veteran user asked them because:

- The question is clear.
- The question provides all the necessary code and not a lot of extra fluff.
- The question shows what the user has tried and didn't work.

These questions, albeit duplicates, can receive more upvotes because people are impressed that a new user asked a great first question. Most users who do any sort of moderating on the site with voting up or down, voting to close, etc. see a long conveyor belt line of useless terrible questions posted by new users that don't show what they've tried, don't show the necessary or any code, etc.

To sum it up, people are surprised to see such well written, constructive questions posted by a new user, thus they reward the user by upvoting it even if it may be a duplicate or very easy question to answer.

Comment: This is not the case. A lot of basic questions with many upvotes don't show any effort. E.g. as OP said "How to get length of string?". Nobody is amazed how well written this question is. It gets thousands of upvotes just because every newbie learning Python googles it. However, it doesn't make sense to grant a newbie, who asked it, a huge reputation.

Answer (score 11):

### Those are pioneer rewards

*"Is it really fair to give so many reputation points to someone that just didn't read the documentation and asked this kind of question (even the question itself is useful)?"*

If it is true that most of these questions stem from the early days of Stack Overflow, then:

Yes, it is fair, because those people were among the **pioneers** who helped making Stack Overflow what it is today. And as any textbook on the history of business will tell you, pioneers in nearly any significant new branch of industry have opportunities to win high rewards.

You might say *"Shouldn't these rewards go to the answers, then, rather
than the questions?"*

Two replies to that:

1. Yes and no. Of course only the answers make the question so helpful.
   But even low-hanging fruit need to be picked by someone.
2. More rewards actually *do* go to good answers than good questions:
   I looked it up in a 957-answer data sample I happen to have at hand
   of questions asked five months earlier, which I
   limited to questions and answers with a score of at least 2.
   On average, **answers get 25% higher score than the respective question**
   and accepted answers get 39.5% higher score than the question.

Comment: I assume you're averaging raw scores rather than rep increases? Because, based on that 25% figure, answerers get 150% more rep than askers (since upvotes are answers are worth twice what upvotes on questions are worth). This assumes no downvotes, which is probably not a *great* assumption, but downvotes would skew the figure even more. So not only do more rewards go to good answers than good questions, but *much* more rep goes to good answerers than good askers.

Comment: Yes, my figures are about raw resulting scores.

Answer (score 4):

Well I think, the more simple a question is, the more it is read, because more noobs than pros are out there.

So even if it may seem unfair that a simple question (like "How to change font in Eclipse") will bring much more reputation to the questioner than a complex and well overthought problem which takes much more effort to ask. But you can say, the simple questions are the more important ones, exactly because they're read more often and also, in my opinion, they widen the range of solved problems on Stack Overflow.

So I would say, it may not really reward effort, but it surely rewards someone for asking a question, that many users need the answer to.

Answer (score 3):

Most of these questions are originals that serve the purpose of helping new people learn the basics of a certain programming language. Back years ago, asking say, how to get the length of an object in Javascript, would have yielded the same results. Generating votes as the years go on, and most importantly, it was an original question.

Ask the same question today and it will be closed as a duplicate. New languages/plugins = new questions. So when a new language comes out and the answer isn't trivial (easily accessible on the docs or something that makes it obvious you've done no research) it will be well received.

Stack's SEO mastery also plays a role -- it makes it so that answers are reliable and at the top of the google search results. Having these questions so easily accessible makes it worth having these "basic questions"

Granted, some people clearly ask similar style questions for sheer rep alone, which doesn't serve the purpose. But I digress..

Comment: "Sterling, Malaury, Archer!"

Comment: How is drawing traffic away from official documentation, or any other quality reference, beneficial to anyone?

Comment: @Servy I often find specific examples from SO are more helpful to me than the actual docs. I usually read the docs, then find examples on Main if there are any. I didn't say Stack dominates the google page 1, it may just be bumped down slightly (or on top, as it often happens)

Comment: @Servy sometimes it helps to have a different example, or the documentation isn't clear to you. I don't see how having both the documentation and an SO question in Google results hurts anybody, and I *do* see how it could help...

Comment: @eddie_cat If the documentation isn't clear then one should be asking a question in that light; explaining what the documentation says, and what the person does and does not understand, so that it can be expanded on.  As for how duplicating the documentation hurts, it wastes the time of everyone involved, and rewards people for behavior that's destructive, incentivising them to continue that behavior, causing a negative feedback loop.

Comment: It doesn't have to draw attention away from the documentation. When answering a question about something that is covered in the documentation, you should link to the documentation. There's nothing wrong with duplicating things that are in the docs. If there was, we'd practically be out of business. Or worse, we'd be a code-debugging service. I thought we had this discussion a long time ago.