# Is "famous question" a bit too easy?

Tags: discussion, badges

I have five of these gold badges, seemingly without effort. [One of them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8530110/in-bash-when-do-lines-need-to-be-terminated-with-a-semi-colon) was a badly worded two sentence question closed as a duplicate, even :)

Meanwhile, I've finally just received my first non-"famous question" gold badge, which required a pretty epic 100 votes on an answer. The difficulty level seems to be out of whack.

All it really seems to do is reward asking a question which lots of people google for.

EDIT

Most comments seem to be interpreting this question as "is there any merit in rewarding people for asking frequently-viewed questions?" It's not. The question is, "is this badge **too easy**?" So, perhaps we could discuss whether the number of views required (10,000 at present) is too low, and should be increased.

The same goes for the silver and bronze badges (Notable Question and Popular Question), with 2,500 and 1,000 views each. My badge counts are completely imbalanced because over them: 13 Notables, 25 Populars. It's a bit ridiculous.

Also, for reference, my "great question" at 100 votes has 63,000 views. So on that single data point, something like 50,000 views would be more in the ball park for a gold badge, rather than 10,000. It's the only question I have with more than 20,000 views, so that seems appropriate.

Comment: [Life isn't fair](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271017/why-newbie-questions-bring-so-many-reputation-points-to-the-author#comment92212_271017)

Comment: If people who are googling for answers often click on a link to StackOverflow, that's a good thing for the site, is it not? It means people are coming here to find information. Perhaps not always an achievement on the asker's part, but just take your gold badges and be happy! Haha.

Comment: Many visitors => more ads => more money. Googleable questions is exactly what stack exchange inc wants.

Comment: It will be ironic if answerers get reversal gold badges too easily for answering this meta question.

Comment: Looking at the badges screen there is about 10X the amount of famous questions (161,601) as great answer (16,098)

Comment: If the problem is that you got a badge for asking a low-quality question, the solution seems to be to ask better questions. :-) But seriously, what's the harm if we award more rather than fewer gold badges for this? Like you pointed out, these people *are* asking questions that lots of people search for. That has to be worth something.

Comment: MSE dupe http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/179552/179419

Comment: Nice. That link gives stats showing just how unbalanced the views-based badges are...and still got downvoted.

Answer (score 14):

You think that the difficulty level seems to be out of whack to achieve a pretty epic 100 votes on an answer. However, there are many examples on Stack Overflow where users have received a Great Answer gold badge for [a two-liner post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1800783/compare-local-git-branch-with-remote-branch/1801150#1801150), just like you received a Famous Question gold badge on [your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8530110/in-bash-when-do-lines-need-to-be-terminated-with-a-semi-colon).

Both the badges happen to be in different leagues. With 10,000 views you just get a shiny gold badge. With 100 votes on an answer, you not only get the gold but also get up to 1000 reputation points (provide you dont hit the daily rep cap). I believe this alone is a good enough reason to have difference in difficulty. Even getting 10,000 views is not easy to achieve.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/mOFCT.png

Comment: The "different leagues" is to the point: The number of *views* will inevitably increase (and it only *can* increase: "What has been seen can not be unseen" :-)). In many cases this is just a matter of time and the number of hits due to people pressing the "I feel lucky" button. The upvotes, in contrast, have to be *earned*. So I basically agree with the asker that it is "easier" to obtain the views-based badges, but would not bargain about it...