# Should a famous question have to be a useful question?

Tags: discussion, badges

I just came across a question asked by a user with a gold badge, but very low rep. Curious about how they got the badge, I discovered it was for a "Famous Question." Curious about what made their other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16067082/correct-way-to-insert-div-tag-on-php) famous, I discovered that it was actually not a very good question. I suppose it just became famous by having enough of the right words in it to google well.

I found [this other meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271099/is-famous-question-a-bit-too-easy) that suggested that a higher number of views should be required to get the famous question badge. I don't know if I really have much of an opinion on that, but doesn't it seem like the question should at least be required to *not be downvoted and closed* in order for it to get someone a gold badge?

I'm not really concerned with "fairness," or keeping score of who has which badges, but a couple of things bother me about this. Whether or not I should, I do tend to take posts from users that have more of them a bit more seriously, at least initially. Maybe that's just me. Also, the help center says:

> Gold badges recognize important contributions from members of the community. They are rarely awarded.

yet there have been more of that particular gold badge awarded than almost every silver badge. Roughly grouping by number awarded, it seems to fit in better with bronze badges. I don't think that really makes sense.

Comment: Side note: that gold badge does not give one any superpowers (unlike tag badges), so not a huge problem.

Comment: "...I do tend to take posts from users that have more of them a bit more seriously..." - If you take them only a bit more seriously then the impact of taking someone a bit more seriously without real merit should only be very small. Almost no harm done. And as you said and also did, you can always check.

Comment: I agree that there really isn't much impact. Also, it occurred to me to check how many questions like that there actually are, and with the search `is:question views:10000.. score:..-1 closed:1`, there are only 508, out of 268943 with just `is:question views:10000..`. So I guess there's not really much impact there either.

Comment: I feel the same way. I try to not let it get to me, but am dumbfounded by some people. The other day, I saw someone with under 1k rep who had 20 Gold Badges for Famous Questions. Really?

Comment: @krillgar I'm really not as bothered by a person with low rep having a bunch of gold badges as I am by the fact that you can get gold badges (eventually) by asking questions that may not actually be any good. And that doesn't really bother me because of "badge envy" or anything like that; it bothers me because according to what gold badges are supposed to be, it seems almost like a bug.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Yeah, I do agree. I think it could also be a factor of the quality of Stack Overflow users (the people complaining about elitism) finding them due to keywords, and absolute basic content. A lot of what I use Stack Overflow for is more specialized, so it just takes me back a little when I see something so simple get that many views.

Comment: @Don'tPanic If you look at the top voted questions for the popular tags you see a lot of very easy to answer questions. However they have a very big amount of votes (also on the relatively easy to find answers) and a very big amount of views. What does it mean? It means these questions are useful to others. Many programmers out there indeed learn programming via Stackoverflow. But still I feel like posing simple (non much (re)searched) questions and having a good chance for many views and many votes seems like a bug to me. The high rated stupid questions bother me more than the low rated ones.

Comment: Perhaps relevant here: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/350340/452046/more-favorites-than-upvotes

Comment: Depends on what exactly "useful" means to you.

Comment: @KevinB I had a hard time deciding how to phrase that. Initially I was going to say "a good question," but I did not want it to sound like I might be referring to the Good Question badge, since I was talking about badges. And certainly "good" is just as subjective. What I meant by "useful" was "percieved by the community to be useful as indicated through voting."

Comment: Ah, I see my disconnect, this badge is rewarded regardless of question score.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Exactly! This badge-envy problem isn't so much of a problem w/badges' values being cheapened (they don't have much value anyway) but giving an incentive to spam Google w/keywords for the sake of getting a badge is bad.

Comment: I've often wanted "This is right in the documentation" as a close reason. I'm not sure whether it's by users failing to do even the most rudimentary research before asking or users trying to game the system by asking extremely basic questions that will surely end up getting a ton of views. Regardless, to me at least, if you can find it in the documentation, it shouldn't be a question here. Unfortunately, there's no way to honestly deal with such questions.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Questions tend to be useful when they're common to multiple people and answered well, neither of which necessarily speaks to the skill of the asker, the quality of the writing, or really much of anything in the *post*.

That said, [this particular question](https://web.archive.org/web/20150223103848/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16067082/correct-way-to-insert-div-tag-on-php) is not useful, and probably attracted that many views due to a woefully misleading title. As it had already been closed, I went ahead and deleted it. There's no "infamous question" badge, so... You gotta kinda read between the lines sometimes.

Comment: feature request: create a infamous badge.

Comment: @Braiam Badges are supposed to reward and encourage good behavior, not bad behavior.

Comment: @TinyGiant Have it show a small poo icon instead of one of the other badges, then we'll know, we'll all know

Comment: Did you link to a wrong page?

Comment: @tim fairly certain that was a joke

Comment: @TinyGiant ah yes.. it went right over my head

Comment: Not a joke, just in a hurry. Amusing 404 page though.

Comment: Hmm.. "infamous question" actually could be useful. If a question is so bad that it is deleted, but so ~good~ that it managed to catch enough attention and points to be gold, then wouldn't the site benefit from having it in a hall-of-shame as an example of how not to ask? Instead of deleting, freeze it, freeze its counters, points, flip the badge to infamous and/or disassociate from owner to not penalize him/etc, put a red frame with blinking BAD BAD BAD letters around it and then put a link on wall of bad examples.

Comment: Hmm, think I'll title my next programming question "Is this Summer Glau naked in this picture?" and see how fast I get the Famous Question badge.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl What if the "Community Wiki" user was the recipient of all the "Infamous Questions" badges? Then we wouldn't be encouraging bad behaviour, but we'd still have a way of quickly accessing all the infamous questions on the site.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder - wish I could upvote your comment.  The poo icon idea deserves a few upvotes.

Answer (score 15):

The mistake here is in assigning any sort of merit to the number of and type of badges a user may have. Some are meaningful in their own way (tag badges are probably your best bet for "authority" in this context), but ultimately, the smartest person with the best answers could have no badges, while the most incompetent country-bumpkin could have a ton. There's no direct correlation to badges and skill or authority (save, again, for perhaps tag badges, which at least display some amount of ability in a particular subject matter).

Even rep I don't think really means much. Low rep could be lots of bad questions and answers, but it also could mean the user is just not very active, or that while their questions and answers may be fine, they haven't garnered much attention. Likewise, I've seen people skyrocket in rep for lucking into answering an extremely basic question that just happens to have a lot of juice with Google.

Ultimately, there's no one size fits all gauge for authority, and in fact, I would say that's a very good thing. You should never just take an answer and accept it as the Word of God, just because it's from someone who seems like they carry a lot of weight. Likewise, the most brilliant and elegant answer could come from someone who only just joined and doesn't even have enough rep to vote yet. Each question and answer has to be evaluated on its own.

Comment: "Not being active" is very true for low rep.  I had someone say "you've been on SO for 3 years and still haven't broken 700 rep."  Which was hilarious to me at the time since 640 of my then 680 rep had been gained in the prior ten days. By the time I went to bed that night I was at almost 800 (their rep? 1 and not a new user).

Comment: If badges are so unimportant, why are they shown at all? The same for rep? Of course I totally agree, that neither are any sort of objective measure of the person's skills or knowledge, but they are obviously there to give a rough indication of how much of a contribution the user made to SO. So yes, in theory they should not influence the credibility of an answer - in practice they do and even if they wouldn't, I too find it strange, if people get "rewarded" for bad questions.

Comment: @MikeMB badges are there to incentivise potentially good behavior / contribution, and they do so but only _on average_, _in the long run_. There is a reasonably solid chance that user with badges did something good, but it's just that - chance. There is no guarantee

Comment: @MikeMB: I'd argue that badges/rep are more for the individual than others. It's the gamification thing. Some users are motivated to answer more questions, review queues, etc. to gain more rep/badges. Conversely, the threat of losing rep discourages many from bad/unacceptable behavior. If it was really intended to be a sign of rank or authority, then answers would be sorted by the rep of the users, which of course they aren't.

Answer (score 6):

I would question the relevance of the "famous question" badge to begin with. Look at the [badge statistics](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges). The "famous question" badge has been awarded 290.3k times.

That is more than for example the bronze badge "critic", awarded for first down vote (230.1k).

Seems all you need to do to get the "famous question" is to spam enough random words that will yield high Google traffic. Or rather, post any kind of crap and with some luck you'll get the badge.

Crappy posts might even have a *higher* probability of getting the badge than good ones. I imagine a question containing nothing but the words "help please code not working" would get this badge fairly quick.

Comment: I think you would have to change that to "help plz code not work" to really rake in the views.