# Why did I get a Notable Question badge on a question with negative score?

Tags: bug, downvotes, notable-question

I just had an odd thing happen. I received a *Notable Question* badge on a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37779104/how-to-rotate-around-center-of-group-in-three-js) I had posted a couple years ago that has a negative score.

I don't really know if it is a problem or bug, it just seemed like kind of a paradox to me.

Should we maybe disallow the *Notable Question* badge for low quality questions?

In response to Erik's comment I would ask you to not upvote the linked question as it will invalidate my example, but I would like to leave the question as a reference.

Comment: I strongly recommend you remove the question link to avoid the meta effect. Notable question is about views, and score is independent of views. Imo we should not disallow this tag for low-score questions. A high-view low-score question is a great indicator that you should adjust your question to be of more use to future readers.

Comment: Have a look https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/27/notable-question

Comment: Seeing a notable question is about the amount of views and not the votes I would say this is status-by-design.

Comment: It had **one** downvote. One. Almost zero. No proof that that downvote was deserved, in fact the question is not that bad. Even with the **one** downvote which is almost nothing at all, it got 1250 pairs of eyeballs on it (and maybe an odd single eyeball). You deserve the swag, you have no say in the matter.

Comment: I think the more relevant question is how you got a question/answer pairing with that many views and that few votes (either up or down).

Comment: Google does not pay attention to the question score.  Nor do the googlers, they are in need of an answer and the question merely provides the search keywords.  Seems you provided enough to get 2500 visitors to look at it.  That is a Good Thing, keeps the company happy too, thus the badge.

Comment: It's possible to get even a Famous Question badge for a not-so-great question. I remembered asking about that a couple of years ago: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315981/should-a-famous-question-have-to-be-a-useful-question

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The notable question badge states:

> Question with 2,500 views. This badge can be awarded multiple times.

...so assuming you don't see a contradiction between a question with a negative score being viewed 2500 times, there's no paradox.

If you had a "great question" badge for one that was heavily downvoted, that'd be a different story.

If you don't feel you *deserve* the badge because it's a bad question, then put the effort in to make it a *better* question that's much more useful to the 2500+ visitors that have found it, and consider the badge compensation for that effort :-)