# Shouldn't the "bounty" system be built into Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, bounty

In light of the recent post - [Laziness is rewarded big time by the reputation system](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271985/laziness-is-rewarded-big-time-by-the-reputation-system/271986#271986), it got me thinking.

Why do we *need* a bounty system? It is woo people into answering somebody's question.

But isn't there an issue here? It creates an economy whereby certain users can sway others solely because of *their own* points.

Shouldn't the system woo people into answering quality questions? Not merely questions with 500 points attached?

What if I happen to have an excellent question without answers; why is there not another way to attract attention to it? It seems like a fairly reliable metric - unusually high upvotes and zero answers.

If a question has 20 or more upvotes and no answers, why not automatically attach a bonus to it?

Comment: If a question gains that many upvotes, the OP also gained enough rep to set a bonus all by themselves.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - Of course , that's true

Comment: I think the admins are working this a little bit with the new [interesting algorithm](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271128/feedback-requested-new-recommended-homepage-algorithm-phase-3)

Comment: @StevenV - sounds good, I'll check this out ! thanks

Comment: Meta.SE dupe: [Automatic system-generated bounties on old, highly-upvoted, unanswered questions in small sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238018)

Comment: @MartijnPieters - ah you got me there, thanks

Comment: It's *extremely* unlikely to find questions with lots of upvotes that don't get answers.  The fact that a question is getting tons of attention is already enough of an incentive for most people to answer.  The advantage of a bounty is the ability to *give attention to a post that is not getting attention naturally*.  Giving extra attention to the posts already getting the most attention isn't actually helping anyone.