# Why are so many useless questions ranked highly, and vice versa?

Tags: discussion, question-quality, hot-questions

I find that more and more new questions consist of useless ponderings of obscure details of languages.

Maybe I am not seeing the questions that involve actual issues. That could be because the obscure useless questions tend to gather the most traction.

A few recent examples (from weekly newsletter):

- [Why mixing + and cast does not produce an error in "+(int)+(long)-1"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28582735/why-mixing-and-cast-does-not-produce-an-error-in-intlong-1?newsletter=1&nlcode=162678%7cb658)
- [Why are floating point infinities, unlike NaNs, equal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28584669/why-are-floating-point-infinities-unlike-nans-equal?newsletter=1&nlcode=162678%7cb658)
- [Function optimized to infinite loop at 'gcc -O2'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28631378/function-optimized-to-inifinite-loop-at-gcc-o2?newsletter=1&nlcode=162678%7cb658)
- [Is it possible to get 0 by subtracting two unequal floating point numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28474339/is-it-possible-to-get-0-by-subtracting-two-unequal-floating-point-numbers?newsletter=1&nlcode=162678%7cb658)
- [What is the size of a boolean In C#? Does it really take 4-bytes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28514373/what-is-the-size-of-a-boolean-in-c-does-it-really-take-4-bytes?newsletter=1&nlcode=162678%7cb658)
- [Is ++x %= 10 well-defined in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27835808/is-x-10-well-defined-in-c?newsletter=1&nlcode=162678%7cb658)
- [For a pointer p, could p < p+1 be false in an extreme case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27272992/pointerp-arithmetic-could-pp1-be-false-in-an-extreme-case?newsletter=1&nlcode=162678%7cb658)
- [Does &((struct name *)NULL -> b) cause undefined behaviour in C11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26906621/does-struct-name-null-b-cause-undefined-behaviour-in-c11?newsletter=1&nlcode=162678%7cb658)
- [Is ‘int main;’ a valid C/C++ program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27777071/is-int-main-a-valid-c-c-program?newsletter=1&nlcode=162678%7cb658)

These questions are all of the academic ponderance type. No one actually needs to know this information. They are being asked for the purpose of gathering points.

For instance, is anyone really hitting that brick wall on the `+(int)+(long)-1` issue?

In general, "why" questions are not useful. It's the "how" that a real programmer is interested in.

The "infinite loop" question is completely useless. It states, in summary "If I do undefined stuff, how does the compile know what to do?" and the answer is "Who cares?". Of course, the real answer is "It doesn't, so it picks a random outcome", which is the perfect answer to "What happens if I do random stuff?".

The big issue I have with this is that all these are useless questions, as in, not helpful to anyone except the question asker (as they get points).

I could give many more examples of useless questions that get major points, but it's not my intention to bore anyone with lists.

Maybe I'm completely mistaken and droves of coders find solace in the intricacies of `+(int)+(long)-1` or it helps them keep their job, solving their hairy `+(int)+(long)-1` issues seconds before the deadline.

What I'd like to know is if anyone else has noticed this trend and how they feel about it. It was my understanding the the goal of Stack Overflow (and it's ilk) was to provide useful help to coders so they can code better code that does real things, such as make a boss happy, or a client, or maybe their kid. But how `+(int)+(long)-1` will accomplish this is beyond me. I seems to me these kinds of questions are off-topic and should be relegated to the '[compiler quirk ponderers](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compilers)' stack exchange site.

- What about these questions is useful or useless, and why?
- Are they a good fit for Stack Overflow's  goal of helping programmers write programs?
- Is it helpful to add these academic questions to the SO archive (i.e. is anyone else actually looking for the answer)?.

Comment: Of your 5 examples, I find 4 of them useful. I have personally encountered 3 of them myself doing normal everyday programming work. So I don't really get where you're calling them "useless" from.

Comment: I should note that the ‘compiler quirk ponderers’ you link to, from a brief glance, appears to be about questions about the theory of compilers and reasons behind common compiler design decisions, not about the specifications of specific programming languages. The questions you object to I believe would be found thoroughly off-topic on the site you link to. Indeed, Stack Overflow is a fine place for these questions.

Comment: I think my point may be missed here. I believe it to be unlikely that someone found `+(int)+(long)-1` in code somewhere and wondered "What does this do". Instead, I believe this question exists only to gather rep. In any case, whether it was real code or not, it seems unlikely that anyone will search for this question. At best, it seems to me to be an exercise in language obscurity. That means it is not meant to solve any real problems.

Comment: I see my question is being downvoted already. Maybe someone is really looking for answers to questions that basically state "I have this crazy code that I know for a fact is ridiculous, but my compiler doesn't complain". How is this useful to anyone? Which program would the 'int main;' question help? Is there anyone thinking "Oh, what is the shortest way to write a program that does nothing, because I really need one and don't want to waste time typing useless brackets"? The question has 95 upvotes so 95 deemed it useful. But how is it useful?

Comment: The problem here is, you can't ask a really useful technical question. Really useful technical questions are very rare. Most of the questions asked are easily answerable by a simple search. One of my most upvoted answers is showing how to concatenate strings in Lua. Is it really useful? No. Because it's already in Lua documentation.

Comment: This whole website is full of useless questions. You can't ask real, unsearchable questions, because they are all off-topic, or opinion-based, or too broad.

Comment: And they expect research effort from you. If I research enough, this website renders useless.

Comment: I almost always find the answer to real problems myself and skip SO altogether. Mostly only basic stuff is easy to find, although sometimes you find some real gems.

Comment: @DDS I gave up already. Filled the contact form to delete my account. I think I'm a bad fit for SO. I don't have questions and answers. The questions I have are off-topic.

Comment: If all you are doing in life is asking "how" rather than "why" then I would suggest that you are missing the point entirely. Might as well be working on an assembly line or flipping burgers. (Which are both entirely honorable professions I might add.)

Comment: Do not cast your Perl before spline.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26716255/why-does-this-program-print-forked-4-times <- Should really be closed, but for some reason it has a +77 score!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

All the questions in your list have been widely "advertised" in so called [Network Hot Questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/hot-questions/info). This explains why these get more than average upvotes.

As for usefulness, as far as I can tell, the list is simply *not intended* to be for useful questions. The original designer of this feature [explained its purpose](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/89364/165773) as follows:

> 

**the intent here is to *explicitly* expose you to the most interesting questions from across the network, whether you have accounts on those sites or not**...

This was posted long ago, but current approach on these seems to be [essentially the same](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/220099/165773):

> what "hot" questions are good for: **entertainment**...

For the sake of completeness, when [Stack Exchange main page](https://stackexchange.com/) was recently redesigned to display hot questions [list](https://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=hot), these were supposed to serve purpose [described as follows](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/238406/165773):

> 

- **We want to talk to users or potential users, not reporters, investors, etc.**
- **We want to focus on *showing* them the kind of content they might find on our sites, with as short a summary as possible of what makes that content better.**

You see, none of above seems to suggest that hot questions are selected based on quality or usefulness.

Comment: That explains nicely how these questions come to gather so much traction. I still wonder about the intent of the askers. Of course, there is not a single 'intent', but it seems to me that it is likely a significant portion of these questions is asked with the explicit purpose of gaining rep.

Comment: I see. I think you might be interested to read this discussion at MSE: [The bikeshed problem and Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/31253/165773). Per my observations, Stack Overflow have built a fairly solid "safety net" to prevent it being flooded by bikeshed stuff; it only leaks somewhat in hot questions. So far this did not seem to be a big issue...

Comment: I was indeed interested in that discussion. I don't think it's the same issue, but I do think it's similar. Of course, puzzles have entertainment value and attract programmers needing a break from their tough nut.

Comment: @DDS well per my recollection, in the past puzzles and code golf questions have been noticeably troublesome for Stack Overflow and exhibited some of bikeshed related "symptoms". But this was generally addressed by establishing a dedicated site: [Code Golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) (with different posting rules). Some of the questions you listed may be considered a CG wannabees (I wrote wannabees because they don't necessarily meet requirements for valid CG SE questions)

Comment: somewhat related: [Laziness is rewarded big time by the reputation system](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271985/839601)

Answer (score 11):

Why such questions are interesting? Because **many** people don't want to be like that guy:

[image: I don't know what I'm doing]

(src: http://i3.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/original/000/234/765/b7e.jpg)

and they want to understand the tools they are using.

While the given examples are not a real programming questions (and if they are, it means that you've read "Clean Code" and made everything opposite), they help to understand how the compiler works, and therefore **may** help you write better, more performant code and avoid many pitfalls.

Comment: Although I completely agree that it's important to understand what a compiler does with your source, I think the examples are way esoteric and useless. Saying that it helps understand the compiler is just finding a problem for a fix, a fix that had no problem other than "how to get more rep". With that, I don't think these questions are (1) meant to help or (2) helping. You'd have to be pretty advanced to do anything useful with these questions. It could be useful for compiler designers. But at this point it's time to go to the computer science SE site.

Comment: this is not quite straightforward. Partly it's purely mechanical: system pushes some (_any_) question into the list and some vote simply because it's shown to them. Atwood called this effect ["self-fulfilling prophecy"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11602/165773). It was especially prominent before they introduced random shuffling. IIRC back then Atwood was laughed at when particularly bland PHP question made it on top of the list and stuck in there. People voted solely because it was #1 and this kept it there so that more people voted, and so on, for almost a week. This looked quite lame...

Comment: I note with a mixture of glee and "I told you so" that this is probably true for the example questions, and perhaps for the [tag:c] tag in general. Subscribe to some other tags and you'll get a completely different picture. Good thing you are not a regular in [tag:php] [tag:regex] ...

Answer (score 5):

> They are being asked for the purpose of gathering points.

Ah, so you’re a mind-reader, are you? I’m not a mind-reader, so I don’t know why these questions were asked. If I were to guess, though, I’d say they were prompted more by curiosity than by a desire to obtain rep points. (Why would anyone bother spending time on Stack Exchange purely to obtain rep points? Such points are valuable only on Stack Exchange: they’re worthless unless you're going to be spending time here *anyway*.)

Curiosity is a powerful thing. All our science, all our tools, all our knowledge of the universe, is built on insatiable human curiosity. People ask questions because of curiosity, and other people find those questions interesting, and vote them up. This is useful, even if not directly so. It prompts learning, and better understanding of the tools we use. Or it sparks interesting patterns in the brain. And in some cases, it actually is directly useful. As others have pointed out, some of those questions actually do have direct practical benefit to some people, if not to you.

Comment: *Why would anyone bother spending time on Stack Exchange purely to obtain rep points?* Because high score. This especially applies to SO; programmers as a general personality type tend to display an affinity for enjoying making their numbers bigger. To put it another way, *why would anyone bother spending time grinding gear in WoW or Diablo?* Are the vast majority of users just here to get a high score? No. Do such users exist? Yes. Are the askers of the questions in question this kind of user? Probably not.

Comment: Also, your SO rep can get you hired. http://www.itworld.com/article/2707360/it-management/your-stack-overflow-reputation-can-help-get-you-hired---by-stack-overflow.html

Answer (score -3):

Because the general attitude of people who use this site so often that they rarely see anything new is best explained by the following:

> With the lights out, it's less dangerous
>
> Here we are now, entertain us
>
> I feel stupid and contagious
>
> Here we are now, entertain us