# Failed audit due to downvote for lack of research effort

Tags: discussion, review-queues, disputed-review-audits

I recently failed a review audit with this question: [how to print 3x3 array in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35903828/how-to-print-3x3-array-in-python)

It is a well formatted question that I downvoted because it showed no research effort.

I thought votes were mine to do what I chose with.

Comment: votes are yours to do what you want with them. In review queues, this is slightly different. Especially when you hit an audit

Comment: Why don't just post an answer @Patrice ?

Comment: @Patrice that may true, but it doesn't make sense. We say "vote the way you want! yolo!" then in review queues we have rules and ways to "validate" that a vote is right or wrong. That just seems backwards to me.

Comment: @CarrieKendall Oh I wholeheartedly agree. My comment was to expose the reasoning, not to defend it :p

Comment: @CarrieKendall I've never said "yolo!" in my entire life and I am offended that you used "we" in a way that could possibly include me ;).

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan yolo

Comment: side note question used in audit gained that many upvotes because it hit the hot list ([Why are so many useless questions ranked highly, and vice versa?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287163/839601))

Comment: @gnat this question is about the First Posts review queue, not the close one.

Comment: unreliable selection of "known good" audits and issues related to it are the same for First Posts and Close queue. The only difference is, such audits [are dismissed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/197484/165773) from close queue (and stop tricking next reviewers) at single vote down or close, while for First Posts audits single vote is not sufficient to drop them off