# Why are there such bad review audits?

Tags: discussion, review-audits

I had [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36533553/how-to-elegantly-cycle-a-list-from-alternating-sides) as a review audit.

The question is super-short and without much explanation. After a bit of inspection, I couldn't tell what he was asking and flagged it. Now I see what he was asking, but the question itself is horribly under-explained. Apparently most people could tell what he was asking, but he didn't really describe what he wanted in the question. Why is this question being used as an audit?

Even the accepted answer is poor quality, since it's code-only.

Comment: see also [Why are so many useless questions ranked highly, and vice versa?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287163/why-are-so-many-useless-questions-ranked-highly-and-vice-versa)

Comment: It was selected as an audit because SO users flagged this question.  Not exactly a mystery why.  High odds that you'll fail the audit when you don't notice that the question is still around and don't otherwise wear a pythonic tinfoil hat.  Makes it a pretty good audit, generally, audits only check if users are paying attention.

Comment: But now you look at the question and it has been closed as unclear. So my decision to flag it during the audit is now *correct*, despite my audit failure.