# Something Wrong with Google's Featured Snippets

Tags: discussion

If you search for "check c# version", the answer at the bottom with 4 downvotes is displayed as featured answer. That's ridiculous.

[image]

Comment: Is that something SO has any control over?

Comment: I assume so. Kind of SEO work in it?

Comment: We have 0 control over this. Afaik Google likes to select lists from the page because it likes displaying step-by-step instructions in those blurbs, and lists commonly contain those.

Comment: We'll get it deleted.  Whether that wises-up Google is unclear, we'll see.

Comment: Related: [Google “answering” my search with link to SE, but not showing the top answer(s)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233845/google-answering-my-search-with-link-to-se-but-not-showing-the-top-answers)

Comment: @HansPassant I think that Google is wise enough already [in that they ignore our votes](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/326696/839601)

Comment: @gnat - turns out that Google actually **did** update their blob, it is now quoting the "is somewhat harder" answer.  No ignoring going on there.

Comment: @HansPassant I doubt that their tweak will be able for longer-term handling of out growing "trouble with popularity". To do it right they would have to access question timeline and account only for "organic" votes - that is, ignore those cast in first week (better month) after question was posted, this is probably too complicated for them to bother

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't going to go out on a limb but since a [there was a note](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/325575/something-wrong-with-googles-featured-snippets#comment353959_325575)...

> We have 0 control over this

...I would like to address that.

It's rather the opposite: **Google has 0 control over this**.

Google can't impact the way how we vote, and the way how we vote seems to be unfortunately getting further and further away from being relevant to content quality and more reflects popularity: [Why are so many useless questions ranked highly, and vice versa?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287163/why-are-so-many-useless-questions-ranked-highly-and-vice-versa)

Stack Exchange management is probably happy with the way how our voting works now, with the way how it emphasizes popular stuff and brings more and more views and cool site visits stats.

But I from my side am also happy with the fact that Google ignores popularity factors in their search results. Because if they wouldn't, my programming searches would probably be polluted with "wildly popular" (and useless) Reddit threads.

Comment: I would like to stress that harm is done by **artificial** popularity and that organic one works really well. If you think of it, using votes to _reasonably_ promote the question could make fantastic results, it's indiscriminate, overused advertising that breaks things...

Comment: ...say, you pick potentially interesting post, advertise it to 100 (200, 300...) more readers then leave it alone. This way it gets good amount of initial feedback and is brought to attention of subject matter experts who do the rest of the work: either tame unjustified enthusiasm with votes down and close or further promote / share it if it's really worthy. This would result in properly "amplified", clean signal - just the right kind for Google. But if instead you mindlessly advertise this post to 1K (2K, 3K...) more readers you will only get unmanageable, useless snowball - flash in the pan