# Can we improve Google's search snippet selection?

Tags: discussion

While we [debate whether acceptance or vote count ought to drive answer ordering](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326095/please-unpin-the-accepted-answer-from-the-top?lq=1), Google ignores both signals and chooses an [unaccepted, negatively voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21612963/290085) for its search snippet:

[image]

Can we influence this decision in some manner?  I would expect that Google would leverage answer votes or acceptance quality signals directly, but since that's not happening, is there an indirect way we could drive what's so prominently shown as this site's main answer to any of its questions?

In this particular case, we can delete the weak answer that parrots the accepted answer without adding value -- and it will be interesting to see how the search snippet changes if that happens -- but can anything be done to help Google choose better snippets in the general case?

Yes, I have clicked the feedback link and provided this feedback:

> Snippet selection should leverage Stack Overflow's quality signals
>   provided by answer score or acceptance selections.  See
>   [Can we improve Google's search snippet selection?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326691/can-we-improve-googles-search-snippet-selection)

**Related**:

- [Something Wrong with Google's Featured Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/325575/something-wrong-with-googles-featured-snippets):
  Similar observation, but no answers; here, I'm not just observing the
  issue but asking what we might do about it.
- https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233858/234215: Answers that we can
  influence this but is 2 years old.  Has any progress been made?

Comment: Regarding your edit: It's only posted as a comment, but [this is from Animuson,](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/325575/something-wrong-with-googles-featured-snippets#comment353959_325575) who works for SE: _"We have 0 control over this. Afaik Google likes to select lists from the page because it likes displaying step-by-step instructions in those blurbs, and lists commonly contain those."_ In other words, there is _nothing_ to do about it but what you've already done.

Comment: @Kendra: Thanks, but there are no answers there.  There is a helpful link to another related question that makes the case that we can influence this, but that answer is 2 years old.  Has any progress been made?

Comment: I doubt you'll get a different answer than what Animuson posted there, but if you insist it's not answered by that, then we'll see what the community says. That was posted this month, so I'd say if that's what an SE member says so recently, then no, there is nothing they can do about it.