# Is question 52264638 good for Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, scope, spam

I recently stumbled upon this question

[Is main a valid Java identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52264638)

The question got a lot of attraction and generates a high amount of reputation in a very short time span. 
Question itself has `273` upvotes. The accepted answer has `248` upvotes.

The curious thing about the question is, that the answer is so trivial, that **anyone with working IDE or basic java knowledge can answer it in a second**.

**Why actuates such a trivial question such an enormous amount of attention?**

Because the actual discussion is not about the question, but about the decision of a teacher!?

**My opinion/feeling**

- My feeling is that this question is bad for Stack Overflow. Judging a person who isn't even part of the community feels wrong.
- Discussing the result of multi choice test is off topic as it is not a programming issue.
- As a motivated user, it feels bad to see such a trivial (and spam?) question debated with that intensity.
- The question was answered in the question itself. It adds nothing but attention to the network. In my opinion this is big problem of most social networks of our time and it turns out that Stack Overflow is also concerned. Wrong metrics at best. 'If it raises attention it must be good'. What a mistake.

**Is this question a duplicate?**

e.g. to [Why are so many useless questions ranked highly, and vice versa?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287163)

I think not. It is really about a specific question on Stack Overflow. But some points of the discussion cited above may fit to my question as well.

Comment: I have rejected your spam flag. This is not what spam is!

Comment: Ok, I learned that! Thank you. Should I reformulate the title as well?

Comment: Depends on what main point you want to ask about…

Comment: You seem to be confusing simple/trivial(?) questions with spam (self promotion/gibberish)

Comment: @deceze *Which mod do I need to blame for declining my spam flag* ... I see my self out ....

Comment: @rene - Ok, this turns out to be fun. My concern is not about triviality but about the intention behind the question. Which is not to solve a programming issue but to get material to argue with the son's teacher.

Comment: @rene but... "I'm Spartacus!" :)

Comment: Would you accept the question if the drama with the teacher had been omitted? It doesn't change anything about the question itself, it's just extraneous backstory.

Comment: Thank you all! This learned me a lot about Stack Overflow. Is Main a river in germany?

Comment: Frankfurt am `main` –– Syntax error

Comment: @jschnasse "My concern is not about triviality but about the intention behind the question." - You can't prove what the intention is. So you have a choice: assume the worst, or assume the best. I would assume the best, it leads to less conflicts.

Comment: @jschnasse editing out you thinking it was spam from the question after your question was answered on the basis of discussing spam was inappropriate IMO

Comment: @WhatsThePoint Should I ask another question? I think for most of the commentators it was immediately clear that `Spam` was the inappropriate term for what I was trying to say. I just didn't know any better. But I'm trying to learn. The answer is still on point. btw. - Cool Name!

Comment: The core question is not bad, but I don't really understand why OP asked it - they already confirmed their answer via the spec and a test program - no-one giving an answer would be able to do more than that. I might say that the question, as asked, is unclear.

Comment: @Dukeling Yes, this was my initial problem with the question. It adds nothing but attention to the network. In my opinion this is big problem of most social networks of our time and it turns out that Stack Overflow is also concerned. Wrong metrics at best. 'If it raises attention it must be good'. What a mistake.

Comment: @gnat It is about this specific question. But you might be right, that the core problem is of more general nature. Sigh!

Comment: @jschnasse The intention doesn't matter, it isn't much different from using an existing [so] question to claim that you're right with your teacher.

Comment: "Boring question with interesting background". -- quoting somewhere.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> My feeling is that this question is bad for Stack Overflow. Judging a
>   person who isn't even part of the community feels wrong.

Why? Because it's easy? We have metric tons of easy and highly upvoted questions. One reason that question is so high up is because it's relatable and popular. It's been viewed over 12.000 times so far. Suggests to me that a lot of people found the question and its answers helpful.

> Discussing the result of multi choice test is off topic.

Is it? Under which close reason would that fall? It's not really too broad, the problem statement is clear and concisely formulated, it's not asking for an off-site resource, it's not a debugging question so no MCVE is necessary...

> As a motivated user, it feels bad to see such a trivial (and spam?)
>   question debated with that intensity.

Spam has a very specific definition on Stack Exchange. We only really consider advertising or complete nonsense posted in bad faith to be spam. That really doesn't apply here. The question is not advertising anything or anyone and is asked in good faith. Talking about it as spam is a red herring.

Comment: My concern is not about triviality but about the intention behind the question, which is not to solve a programming issue (there is no issue, the OP knows the answer very well) but to get material to argue with the son's teacher.

Comment: @jschnasse is that bad? Stack Exchange is a repository of questions and answer. The OP asked a genuine question (there is no requirement to not know the answer beforehand) that was well recieved and apparently also searched for by many other people on the web, and obtained a high quality answer (someone spent a lot of time writing up the exact justification for it). I don't see how the material objective behind asking the question is a matter of concern here, after all, we even allow self answered questions.

Comment: Ok, thank you! I think this lesson learned me a lot about Stack Overflow!

Comment: question views and votes here are only because it has stuck in [meta-tag:hot-questions] sidebar for a while, I saw it there myself ([reading timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52264638/timeline) suggests that it has been in hot list for about 4-5 days). As for the quality, since I happen to use mostly Java I can tell you that both the question and answer are trivial useless trash, not worth even half of screen estate they occupy. "One of my kids is taking Java in high school blah blah", gimme a break