# Hot Network Questions should "really" change

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts

My question is strongly related to this one: [Where's the new boatload of experts who can explain stuff to me like I'm five?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392414/8620333)

@CodeCaster asked *"Is it something that should change? How?"* and I guess we could at least change how HNQ are selected because, well, it only select trivial questions getting a lot of trivial answers (in most of the cases).

Today, this CSS question was selected as HNQ: [Float icon to left and text to the right](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59559606/8620333). In the CSS world this is a very basic question. Who never saw in his life a structure with icon on the left and text on the right? Ironically, the HNQ sidebar implement such feature.

Unfortunately, this question is now Hot, getting a lot of upvotes and we are showing to the world this question as a *good* example of what SO contain. For me, this is actually a very *bad* example.

The same day we got this question: [Why margin-left of a BFC element cannot get a same result as margin-right of a float element?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59559477/8620333). A very intresting one about some complex stuff related to CSS and I know only two users who can answer such question accurately. One of them did it perfectly as expected. Now this question is far in the list and no one will notice it...

---

I will not blame the algorithm because it was designed to work that way as explained [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/60756/386331) and more precisely this formula:

```
(MIN(AnswerCount, 10) * QScore) / 5 + AnswerScore
-------------------------------------------------
         (QAgeInHours + 1) ^ 1.4
```

But checking this: [Updating the Hot Network Questions List - now with a bit more network and a little less "hotness"!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/325060/386331) I can read that:

> Moderators have the ability to remove questions from the HNQ List.

Are moderators using this ability? if so, when? can't we use this feature to clean the HNQ list in some particular case? After all, Moderators are also expert so they can identify *trivial* questions selected as HNQ.

I know that this can easily be considered as opinion based and some will not agree with my opinion. I am ok with it but I am pretty sure we all agree that some questions doesn't *really* deserve to be Hot. We can probably allow people to flag question to be removed form HNQ or use the Meta chat to discuss about a particular one or any other idea that will keep the HNQ at a minimum level where we can really see intresting questions.

---

Worth to note that I am not against* having such question in the site since it's on-topic even if it clearly lack research effort. I simply don't like how we highlight such question when SO should be a high quality Q&A website. If we cannot stop such low effort question let's not help them to become popular and encourage more of them.

<sub><sub><sub>* to be fair, I would love to not see such question...</sub></sub></sub>

Comment: I have, I believe, manually kicked a question off of HNQ *once*. It was a question that I, as a domain expert, personally felt was not a good fit for HNQ. I couldn’t make that same call about a CSS question, as I’m not a domain expert. You, of course, can kick the question off of HNQ yourself, as a domain expert, by marking it as a duplicate. If it’s as basic as you say, then surely it’s a duplicate, considering how long this site has been around answering questions.

Comment: @CodyGray This time I failed to find a duplicate which is also frustrating because I am pretty sure there is at least one if not more. Sometimes, it's not easy to find *easy* stuff.

Comment: ok, I found duplicates. I couldn't sleep without finding them!

Comment: It feels a bit like the questions that go on the HNQ should be reviewed by experts. Or should even be screened by experts before they even go on there. Although, I also suspect this is probably too heavy handed... Still, the algorithm clearly doesn't pick *good* questions. In fact, if a question has a lot of answers in short amount of time that's usually an indication it's very low effort "give me the code" with a trivial problem usually solved many times and many users just jump at the opportunity to reap some fast rep.

Comment: HNQ should be deleted outright.