# The Fight Against The FGITW and Dupe Ignoring

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, moderation, fastest-gun

There have been many questions about solutions to FGITW, or people who answer anything because rep. Over the years.. obviously there's been no to minimum mitigation of this and we all know it's bad.

1. Because it encourages new users that they don't have to do any research
2. It makes it harder to curate the site when people refuse to follow the rules

Now, some people genuinely might not know a question is an immediate duplicate based on the suggested links *and that's ok*. When we get into higher rep users who are intimately familiar with the site rules, it has a harder effect.

A moderator suggested I bring this up, because I am asking the moderators and the community:

Would we be ok with mod flags against these offending users? These flags are obviously subjective to the handler, but if we could come up with, as a community, a guiding standard we could encourage moderators to take up a stand to help the curators of the site fight a losing battle.

Examples:

1. an obviously established user answers a question that is closed as a duplicate. This duplicate is obscure, hard to find, incorrect, etc. The answerer is flagged, and receives no punishment. (This is good)
2. an obviously established user answers a question that is closed as a duplicate. This duplicate is well known, very visible on SO, or very visible on google SEO results. This user is flagged and receives a moderator handled punishment (maybe a 1 day answer ban.. not sure here, please feel free to suggest).
3. a lower rep user does the exact same as example 2. Leniency may be applied here because of their status in the community. This would obviously require a bit of research into the user, because there are definitely low-rep users who are extremely well versed in using SO.

These examples all pertain to moderator subjectivity. But it is also up to us, the community, the ones who would be casting the flags, to do our due diligence. Adverse punishments to flaggers could be placed if flags are deemed to be malicious in nature, targeted (tricky one), etc.

This is not an issue we need tools for, we simply need a consensus agreement, and the dedication to handle it ourselves.

This question focuses on community solutions because of how long it takes SE to develop (this is not a negative note, it's just how it is because of their staffing and quota backlog), on top of them perhaps even shutting down the idea. This is a power we can take into our own hands

Comment: If someone wonders, FGITW = fastest gun in the west (someone trying to answer a post as fast as possible, mostly to gain the most profit/reputation by being the first to answer (first answers are mostly shown as the top answer due to sorting)).

Comment: @Tom thank you, I forgot to make that clarification, very much appreciated!

Comment: For context: "Well established" / "High rep" means 5-digit or 6-digit rep. These are users that have been _very_ active for a long time and simply don't seem to care about curating a repository of _quality_ content.

Comment: *"an obviously established user answers a question that is closed as a duplicate."* ... that part is unclear to me. Do you mean the question is already closed and someone reopened it or do you mean the answerer answered before the question got closed and maybe before even the first flag/vote to close was cast?

Comment: @Tom another good question. What I mean is that an answer is posted, and then closed as a duplicate, by a user who should have casted a close vote instead. This is why if the close vote is subjective (reopen votes are cast for variety of reasons) there is no penalty because it's not an obvious duplicate.

Comment: There's a few problems with flagging these, with a custom flag, in my opinion. 1. Custom flags are slow to dealt with (this isn't a complaint about that), therefore by the time they are dealt with the "damage" is done. 2. The Mod *needs* to agree the answer is a duplicate, which if they don't know the language, they won't know. 3. it's not the job of the mods to denote if an answer is good (or bad) as a moderator; that's the role of the community. *TL;DR It's the community that needs to agree to actively not answer Dupes, and there are too many users that only want the internet points...*

Comment: @Larnu this is why I mentioned that this is a moderator and community effort in which everybody has to agree that "this is ok". The damage may be done, but punishments can still be passed to offending users. I 100% agree that the main solution is we as users agree to look for dupes, and cast votes before answering. Unfortunately, without a negative consequence (I personally can't bring myself to downvote a correct answer) this will never be achievable.

Comment: @Larnu That's correct involving mods can be troublesome, because they shouldn't be expected to be experienced in that context. But there is a simple way to avoid including mods and still fix this issue here: retract rep points when the question gets closed (re-add when it gets reopened and keep the points when the answer is older than 6 (?) months, similar to the rules when deleting a post).

Comment: @Tom while I believe that's a great solution, it requires intervention on SE's part and tooling. Until something like that happens, it's in our own hands to try and solve it.

Comment: Correct and in my opinion that's the only really working way, we need SE's to do something here. They already did that when they retracted points when a post gets deleted.

Comment: consensus would probably be easier to achieve if [this feature request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/352450/839601) was implemented

Comment: I don't see punishing users who are contributing the most content to the site with suspensions due to choosing not to take moderation action (voting to close) as a sustainable solution. I don't think we have the tools to handle this ourselves adequately.

Comment: like, at what point does a user go from being a benefit to the community to doing more harm than good? how much good is one answer on a duplicate worth? If a user has answered 2k questions that aren't closed, do they get away with a few bad answers every now and then? how many? If we have actual numbers i'm sure someone could pull up some stats to see how many people would be affected by it.

Comment: There's also the other side of this: VTC a question as a duplicate when it is not.  Some of these (non-)closures are debatable.  Is it really a dup or is it just close?  And sometimes you get an answer on the new question (which may itself be better) that is better than the "original", and the older question should be closed as a dup of the newer one.

Comment: I think majority of the problem are users <3k who are not familiar how closing works or why it is important. They are the problem, not the established users. If an expert provides a high quality answer that is similar to some other answer I see no harm in doing it. If either of these answers are found later on the goal is achieved. Low-rep users on the other hand provide low quality answers, so deleting those is helpful.

Comment: Sure, let's just chase all the answerers off the site! Who needs experts?! It's not like the answer per question rate is tanking... oh wait, it is. The inaccuracy of closure, and the disagreement surrounding closure, makes this a non starter because you will simply introduce injustice in a situation that isn't causing problems.

Comment: To aid the Mod in assessing the flag, it could be a prerequisite that the flagger _also_ has VTC'd the Q.

Comment: @Dharman "Low-rep users on the other hand provide low quality answers". I'm not sure I agree with you there, being a low-rep user myself. I'm also not sure that having separate rules for when a user is **allowed** to Answer a Question is encouraging either. Seeing a high-rep user gaining more rep fast doing things that low-rep users aren't allowed to do isn't exactly going to bridge the gab.

Comment: @Scratte I was speaking in general about people with <50 rep only starting to answer questions. They come and see and easy question and instead of closing they post an answer. High-rep user have high reputation not because they are entitled, but because they worked hard.

Comment: @TravisJ "injustice"? Really? Let's keep the hyperbole down, please. And if answerers are chased off by not being able to answer crap questions and duplicates, were they really interested in the (original) mission of Stack Overflow anyway? The answer per question rate is dropping because SO has made it their mission to welcome any and all questions, irrespective of whether experts want to answer them.

Comment: What do you want the moderator who handles such a flag to ***do***?

Comment: One proposal I had in mind was to introduce a delay before anyone could post answers. That would leave more time for people to find the right duplicate, and if the question could be answered in seconds, that probably means that it's a duplicate all right. But that idea didn't seem very popular. It exists here too: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251744/throttling-trusted-users

Comment: It is a topic well worth discussing – but IMO especially that second duplicate-of already touches upon all possible solutions. So, why re-open this and fragment the discussion?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove the incentive for FGITW to answer well known dupes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316564/remove-the-incentive-for-fgitw-to-answer-well-known-dupes)

Comment: @StephenRauch I saw that question before I posted, there's a difference between removing the incentive and actually handing out punishments

Comment: I one day use Mod flag for such behavior and got nothing: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/371710/8620333

Comment: How do we solve the real issue: FGITW get those +3, +4, +5 every time he answers poor question? Sand and pearl is not the correct interpretation when the question is a clear dupe  and the amount of upvotes on answers reach the double digits.

Comment: @xdtTransform it's even worse when the question become HNQ because of the amount of upvotes (related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392597/8620333)

Comment: This proposal argues for dealing with the dupe problem with the proverbial [stick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrot_and_stick). In contrast, this other recent proposal makes a case for dealing with the dupe problem by dispensing *carrots*: [It's time to reward the duplicate finders](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394048/1497596).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Just make it a throttle like anything else. If x of your answers are deleted or on posts that were closed (for any reason) within y time period (a week?), your answering ability is throttled for a period of time.

No moderator intervention needed.

It's not an outright ban so they can continue to answer, but they have to pick and choose which ones they do because they can't just freely answer everything again until they're outside of the throttle window. This would only impact users who routinely answer low quality/close-worthy or duplicate questions.

Comment: While this is another great solution, it's a tooling requirement or coding requirement on SE's behalf. And let's be honest, even if it's deemed a good idea, the implementation is notoriously slow on their part (not a bad thing, just how things are)

Comment: Isn't there already a check on deleted answers and answer scores?

Comment: There might be, but most of the throttles that i know of related to answer/question throttling get essentially ignored once you get past a certain threshold... and the particular activity we're talking a bout here very quickly goes way past it.

Answer (score 15):

**No.**

- We focus on content, not users. Using a sliding scale depending on the perceived standing of the author and what one subjectively feels "the author *should* have known" is a recipe for disaster and personal squabbles. Leave that out of the discussion, period.
- Don't discourage potential answerers. The percentage of answered questions is already tanking,* putting up more barriers through threatened punishment means even more questions will go unanswered because people will shy away from answering if they can't be certain they won't be punished. You're creating a minefield there in an already war-torn region.
- Even the highest standing users can have a weak moment and simply feel like answering that particular question which somehow tickles their fancy, or they were truly unable to find the right duplicate in that moment. It happens. You have no idea why or how it happened, how can you judge it? If it's a good answer, what is the point in ***punishing*** people for it?
- If the answer is no good or the question gets deleted anyway, the author doesn't receive any reputation for it anyway and it was their wasted time. What more punishment do you need?
- Can we get away from a culture of punishment and towards a culture of promoting and rewarding *good* behaviour? Outright offences must be punished; I'd count trolling, spamming and continuous bad contributions among that. Good behaviour must be rewarded. Merely *meh* behaviour should be neutral; posting a decent answer on a duplicate question counts as *meh* ‍♂️ to me. Maybe they *could* have done better, but they certainly didn't do anything deserving punishment.

* Note that I believe the *question quality* is the biggest culprit here, but we don't want to be adding another reason to that.

Comment: I agree with you, point by point.

Comment: As I saw it pretty often: how about "Try this <uncommented code>" verbatim copies from the same user on the same day on duplicated questions ?

Comment: @Tensibai Is the code apropos to the question and does it help? For those kinds of answers, *mostly probably no.* Downvote. Move on.

Comment: @Tensibai vote down, explain why. Do not forget to add the link to the previous  answer from the same author. Of course if you know that question is a duplicate vote to close the question.

Comment: So copy/pasting answers is ok. Just close as dupe don't bother if the answer author reopen. Noted.

Comment: @Tensibai Verbatim copy-pasted duplicate answers already have their own automated check and associated punishment. No need to conflate that into this topic…

Comment: @Steve no thanks, I've tried and it didn't turn good. It's disheartening to close to a duplicate answered by the same person so often... That's sounds gaming the system to me but seems it is not at all...

Comment: I think that a verbatim copy of another answer is something to be flagged for moderators attention see here for example https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320351/how-to-handle-copy-and-pasted-answers-from-dupes

Comment: _"We focus on content, not users"_ What about users that don't focus on content? Or that only focus on quantity over quality?

Comment: "Question Quality" can be addressed by dupe-closing dupes. This answer isn't considering _very_ active tags where _mediocre (or plain bad) answers_ on obvious duplicates _get upvotes_ regardless of the fact it should've been closed instead of answered. This isn't a "weak moment". Those users ___systematically___ answer instead of dupe-closing questions.

Comment: @Cerbrus If those answers are mediocre or bad, *they should be downvoted on that metric already*, the consequence of which should be eventual answer-banning of that user! If that system isn't working, we should figure out why and tweak that. We shouldn't need to introduce another subjective vigilante measure in addition to that. At least not as it is described here, since that's really a minefield as I see it.

Comment: @deceze: _That's the whole point of this question_. Experienced users are answering questions that should be closed, and aren't getting answer-banned, because of the humongous amount of rep they have already. On top of that, new users don't know this, see a working answer, and upvote it, ___rewarding___ users that systematically answer instead of dupe-closing questions.

Comment: @Cerbrus Then again, the system should be tweaked. E.g., if you're having a bad answer streak, you're timed out for a while, regardless of your existing reputation. You can set metrics for "bad answer streak" to whatever we can agree on, which could also include that the question was closed as a duplicate. But manually going around flagging users based on subjective judgement and letting moderators dole out punishments sounds like a terrible idea to me.

Comment: So, you’re basically saying: this is a problem, but it requires extra / changed tooling, not mod flags?

Comment: @Cerbrus I wouldn't even necessarily agree that it *is* a problem. FGITW answers on questions which end up being closed as off-topic are arguably problematic, but often those questions end up being closed and roomba'd anyway; nobody gains anything from those long-term. If a question is a duplicate, that means it's at least somewhat on-topic, and I have a hard time seeing how a *good* answer to an on-topic question is problematic. Even if closing it as a dupe might have been the *better* course of action.

Comment: The problem is that those questions ___aren’t getting closed___ because repwhores keep answering them.

Comment: @deceze Would be true if the answerer wasn't a gold tag owner reopening after closure to be sure to get the accepted +15 too... As I said, there's people gaming the system, this question is about them overall

Comment: Just look at the most active users answering [tag:javascript]...

Comment: @Cerbrus FWIW, most of those top Javascript users supply *excellent* content to the site and I highly respect them. I doubt many of them do it for "repwhoring" (BTW, that's not PC anymore…). As much as we can agree or disagree on that point though, **this proposal as is isn't it!** It's way too subjective and reeks of vigilantism. Without a clear measurable metric against which to punish answerers this isn't workable.

Comment: ... Which is why this is a discussion, not a feature request. And yes, in the top 5 active this month there's users that are very actively repwhoring. Users that have been reminded to close obvious dupes time and time again.

Comment: …which is why I'm discussing against this vehemently.

Comment: There's no need for vehemency, like I said in the question, it requires a consensus agreement between moderators and users. And it's unlikely for that to happen, but it's always worth voicing.

Comment: @Sterling Trying to introduce any measure of subjective judgement *on users* is something I feel I need to vehemently discourage. We. Do. Content. Period. Let's not even start thinking about trying to judge users directly. A user's status within this community is determined by their content contribution, not the other way around. We may or may not need to address this problem and there may or may not be ways to do it; this here is going into a dangerous direction, so this isn't it.

Comment: The direction this should be going in, is fixing the broken answer ban system...

Comment: I think your point of discouraging answers because of the metrics is a bit more than that. Answers declined because of other SE related issues, much like how to mod queue slowed down due to the resignations. Are the number of answered questions really *that* important when the majority percentage doesn't even belong here in the first place? You're absolutely correct when quality is the culprit, but we don't close quality questions.

Comment: Just to be clear, my intentions are not malicious. I only have content quality in mind, and there's no ill will when I say punishment, but I will concede that I think differently than others -- some people see a downvote as harassment or rude, whereas I simply don't. So my ideas sometimes aren't accepted because of such ways of thinking.

Comment: @Sterling The only issue I have with your proposal is that the criterion is vague, subjective “you should have known better.” And then you expect moderators to act on that. It’s already hard enough when trying to be objective and sticking to facts, but your proposed yardstick is extremely bendy and flexible. This *will* introduce interpersonal issues, it’s just a matter of time. That’s why: no. Let’s stick to something that at least *could* be automated in theory.

Comment: @deceze I wholeheartedly agree, but that requires tools and well... we already know how hard those are to get. :(

Comment: @Sterling I agree, but frankly, recently the mothership has been sending out some signals which make me quite hopeful that they’re turning this thing around and will actually focus on such issues again.

Comment: @cerbrus as you mentioned "the javascript top 5" ... at least three of them use their votes appropriately (or to be clear: I think they are among the top curators in js too). That they are in the top 5 suggests that earning reputation has nothing to do with not focusing on quality. ... I'm curious how you draw your conclusions ... cause I haven't seen you in [js] for some time ....

Comment: @JonasWilms what does my answering behavior in a tag have to do with my ability to observe what people are doing? Please don’t presume to know how active I am on SO. You have no idea.

Comment: There's a grace period while you can answer a closed question. How about no rep for an answer upvoted during the grace period? The timer is already running, maybe it could be applied to this "rep ban" too ..?

Answer (score 7):

### Let's have a **delete vote queue**

I close a lot of question each day as duplicate but I would really like to delete many of them. Actually when I vote to delete a question, only few of them get deleted by other users (from the delete tools) otherwise I am obliged to make a delete request somewhere to bring more attention but its very boring, not easy to handle, not accurate, bad ..

If we had a better mechanism for deletion or if the delete tool was more visible to users it would be good but the best is to have a queue like we are doing with close votes/reopen votes.

---

> This question focuses on community solutions because of how long it takes SE to develop
> on top of them perhaps even shutting down the idea. This is a power we can take into our own hands

I know that a new queue need some Dev to be done but we can at least encourage users that close questions as duplicate to get back to them and delete them (There is some good userscript that can help doing this). We can also encourage them to visit the tools from time to time and check the delete requests. SO can also do a tiny effort to make that tool more prominent. Why not also giving more delete votes to users?

I remember that [somehwere in the site](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) we can read the following:

> When should I delete questions?
>
> Closed questions that are of no lasting value whatsoever should be flagged and deleted.

and

> How many times can I vote to delete per day?
>
> At 10,000 reputation, you can cast 5 delete votes per day. An additional vote is granted per 1000 reputation, to a maximum of 30 delete votes per day.

let's increase the number of votes. 5 is too low.

---

**TL;DR**

I guess delete votes is the best weapon against *The FGITW and Dupe Ignoring*. They will keep wasting their time/effort to earn reputation that will be lost in few days. At the same time, we keep the site *clean* from repeated duplicates.

Comment: 'nother queue? I'm not so sure about that.

Comment: Are you saying you close as sup, then vote to delete?   IMHO that's not a good strategy.   If a Q is delete-worthy you should vote to close for whatever reason it's deletable.   Qs closed as dup should have _some_ value

Comment: Dupe-voted questions aren't necessarily delete-able. And even if we could delete half of the questions these users answer, that still wouldn't mean a thing to those users... They need _repercussions_, other than gaining a little less rep.

Comment: @chrisneilsen I don't delete *all* the questions I close as dup but I delete the trivial duplicate that are repetead again and again and where 5 answers appear in only few minutes and where I find the duplicate target by simply googling the title. Those questions have absolutely no value and should be deleted. Those question are the one used by Users to gain easy Rep.

Comment: @Cerbrus *Dupe-voted questions aren't necessarily delete-able* --> I know. I am talking about the repeated ones that we can easily find (like described by the (2) in the question). By doing this we make their effort useless and with time they will understand that it's *useless* to keep adding answers that will get deleted but unfortunately few people are around to consider judging and deleting questions. Even if we have repercussions we also need to clean what they have done.

Comment: @TemaniAfif: There are users that delete those answers themselves, when called out on it. Deleting the question / answer for them just saves them the effort. Having a answer like that deleted isn't a repercussion. The point of this question is to make it happen less. Not to clean up afterwards.

Comment: @Cerbrus *The point of this question is to make it happen less. Not to clean up afterward* --> my idea behind the clean is to make it happen less. I remember a user asking on meta complaining about his answers getting deleted very often and wanted to stop contributing due to this. This is what I am looking for. Many users will get upset with this and will starting thinking to contribute differently or will stop. I am not sure if it will work or not but it's something we can try since it doesn't require a lot of effort to spend all our delete votes to *clean* bad questions.

Comment: Considering the fact these users have a habit of answering questions that often end up deleted already, I'm sceptical this would change anything in their behavior.