# close votes and other moderator activities should be incentivized

Tags: discussion, reputation

The platform incentivizes answering, but doesn't incentivize moderator activities. Many users answer duplicate questions for easy reputation rather than voting to close as intended. perhaps a good way to balance the equation would be to reward those of us who perform actions like editing and voting to close. just my opinion, what say ye?

Comment: I totally envision more of *You closed my question only for the reputation!* which could be a valid argument when we implement your suggestion.

Comment: On SE we don't call reputation "karma". Please be careful if you introduce a new tag.

Comment: Giving an incentive to close isn't going to stop FGITW, nor is it likely to have a good effect on the community, with people trying to get those incentives for questions that shouldn't be closed. Internet Points have "value" to some people; that's always how they've played the Stack Overflow "game".

Comment: related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394048/8620333 / https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394602/8620333

Comment: `Some days there are 70 -90 % of closed question, in the tag mysql, most of the user help, even if they don't like the mods

Answer (score 8):

The only real incentive I'm looking for is some encouragement that continuing to do those actions is the right thing to do, and that we would be publicly defended when doing so.

I suppose that's one way to say I agree with this, but again - the only thing I want is the company to shield us from social media's perception of what we do and why we do it.

Once one has Enough™ internet points, one's focus can shift away from that to the actual point of all of this.

Comment: Enough = 0.1 Skeet ?

Comment: @rene I thought "one Enough" is 20K points :) - we need committee do decide

Comment: Makoto - could you clarify if you are for "points" used to incentivize or not (I think you are against, but not sure).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov:  Points aren't shielding us from social media's perception of why we do what we do.

Comment: @rene:  Kind of why I trademarked it - enough means different things to different people so I wouldn't be surprised if someone with 1,500 rep or less doesn't think they have "enough" to justify doing any mod activities at all.

Comment: Can I sub-license Barely Enough?

Comment: I expect moderation activities are easier with more privileges. Those are only gained with reputation. 1500 reputation means edits are not instant, so lots of Skipping in queue are done (by me) because most edits would be too trivial to send to a queue. Wouldn't that in itself be enough to justify not moderating? Even skipping takes time. Then there's the almost duplicate answers to multiple questions. What can I really do about those? Flagging the Questions as duplicates ends up as aged away, and I can't flag any of the answers.

Comment: Please continue doing these actions! They are the right thing to do! (Does that help? Feel free to let me know if you need any more encouragement.)

Comment: @CodyGray:  Yeah, hearing that from a diamond mod is kind of a given.  Seeing it as a part of a blog post or as a part of the company's manifesto would be more my point.

Comment: I don't have a blog. :-(

Comment: @CodyGray: It'd probably also not catch my attention the same way that the official blog does. :P

Comment: Doubtful. Have you read the official blog? I bet you'd find my hypothetical blog more interesting.