# A way to identify a future popular question

Tags: discussion, canonical, quality-improvement, answer-quality

After around three years contributing on SO I have noticed the following for many of the old questions I have answered:

- They are *popular* with a big number of views and votes.
- They didn't even cross 100 views in total and the only votes are the ones made few hours after the question was asked.

Well, I am not introducing something new since this is the logical result of SEO and other aspects we all know about.

My concern here is that when I answer a new question, I cannot know if it will become popular or not (no one can do I guess). It's also difficult to *force* a question to become popular. I tried many times to edit/improve many questions/answers, but it's not trivial to find the correct keywords and the best title in order to make it rank higher in search results.

Since it's difficult to make a question popular, I am wondering if there is a way to **early** identify that a question will become popular.

With such information we can spend effort editing answers to make them canonical. Writing canonical answers isn't an easy task and sometimes we do it for the wrong question (a question that no one will see ...) and in many cases we write a one line answer and it become very popular and gather a lot of votes.

I insist on the *early* factor because:

- We may notice very late that a question is popular or we may never notice it because no one will give an upvote to a *basic and very simple* answer we initially gave: We end with a high ranked question not really useful.
- Someone will add a new and better answer than yours because the question become popular. This is good but we end with the common situation where the accepted and *very simple* answer is on the top and the *very detailed* answer is on the bottom.
- It's better to edit the answer when the number of views is at 5K than when it's at 30K. This will keep the content quality of SO at a high level since we will target 25K with a good content.

An indicator for *a future popular question* would be very useful and will for sure improve the overall quality of SO since it will keep our effort focused on the right questions.

### What have you tried?

The only *idea* I got is to use SEDE to get the number of views and the creation date to have a kind of ratio (views/duration) but this won't be very accurate because:

- a question can be popular for a short time of period then nothing (due to HQN or social sharing)
- a question can be edited after a period of time and the number of views will start to increase or stop increasing (difficult to notice this change)
- not all the tags have the same popularity
- etc.

I also thought about storing the number of views each week to have a kind of graph, but this is a lot of work...

I am wondering if anyone have a *clever* idea or should I stick to my ratio to approximate this.

---

I also think this can be a good feature on SO. I would love to have a notification like: *"Hey, this question is becoming popular, consider editing your answer to earn more upvotes!"*. The SO team can develop an algorithm that can easily detect the trending of a question. At least they have more tools than me to do it.

Again, I would imagine such feature a good one that will help increasing the content quality of SO.

<sub>I am not implying that we should neglect some questions. I simply want to know where it's the best to have a canonical answer.</sub>

Comment: "I am wondering if there is a way to early identify that a question will become popular." Lowest common denominator. The more easily someone can hit a problem, the easier for the question to become a hit.

Comment: Isn't this what the HNQ already does?

Comment: And for the record, **popularity doesn't make a question good.**  Quite the opposite, actually.  There are a few exceptions, however: [this question about memory handling in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218), for example.  Nobody unfamiliar with C++ understands it or particularly cares about it, but *everyone* understands and is very interested in what happens when you leave a book in a drawer in a hotel room and steal the room key.  Undefined Behavior is Undefined.

Comment: Answer all of the basics in [tag:deno] and you'll have a few hundred upvotes by the end of the decade.

Comment: "Since we cannot control which question can be popular, I am wondering if there is a way to early identify that a question will become popular." This reads to me like: X is impossible, so let's try X, which would be rather futile. Where exactly is the difference between controlling and predicting?

Comment: @RobertHarvey *popularity doesn't make a question good* this is exactly what I am trying to fix here. If I have a metric to let me know that a question is becoming popular then I can improve my answer there to make it *good* enough since a lot of people will see it. By the way, HNQ doen't do this. HNQ consider the number of answer and the number of votes and having many answers means that the question is either trivial or a clear duplicate. It's rarely a good one (related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392597/8620333)

Comment: @Trilarion By controling I mean editing the question to make it more SEO friendly. It's like you have a website and you try hard to make it rank first. You have a question about a particular issue and you try to get the first one when we search about that issue (so it's popular). You cannot control this because many questions will cover the same issue and few of them will rank high. Knowing which one is on its way to become popular will help me focus on it rather than trying to edit other questions that will never become popular.

Comment: @ggorlen upvotes isn't really an issue because we can easily get them with basic answers to very popular questions. What I want is that all the answers I gave to *popular* questions are canonical or with enough detail to fix and explain the issue. I would like to do this as soon as possible and not wait until the question is at 30K views

Comment: If we would subscribe to the theory that almost all important programming questions about existing technology have already been asked on SO then one may be able to limit the possibility of popular questions yet to be asked on SO to those areas where new technology arrives. Basically disregard all questions that are not about really new things.

Comment: @Trilarion based on my experience it's not always the case. Surprisingly some questions about old stuff get a high popularity in a short time of period while question about new things don't get popular (or maybe will be in the future). If I have all the analytic tools for SO I can do such study since it's about stats analysis. I simply need to follow the number of views and see how its increasing. By the way, we already have an example of tool that gives us some stats https://stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=stats&daterange=today but it's not really what I am looking for.

Comment: i can help when it comes to tracking statistics to make a graph for views and votes overtime , i would use selenium to make an automation code that would run every day and check every question and answer and store the information , what you think ?@TemaniAfif

Comment: @Asmoun well, It would be a good idea :) no need to write a full code and waste your time, You can answer this question by describing how you will create the automation (the main steps), it can be helpful to a lot of people and we can probably use it for different cases ;)