# Is "How does Google Chrome decide what to highlight ... ?" really a high quality question, belonging on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, disputed-review-audits

During First Posts reviews, I got this audit question: *[How does Chrome decide what to highlight when you double-click Japanese text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61672829/how-does-chrome-decide-what-to-highlight-when-you-double-click-japanese-text/61686940)*.

It is a "*How does a piece of software do something*" question. There is no problem to reproduce or resolve, no goal to reach, no expected results, since there isn't even any coding involved, so I find a more of a [Super User](https://superuser.com/tour) or [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tour) question and I have flagged it accordingly, and got this:

[image]

So, should this be considered as a good SO question? Maybe, because it does, after all, explore a certain algorithm, but since it does not meet most of the criteria described on [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), is it a good idea to make it an audit question?

Comment: From time to time, bad questions sneak by moderation, and ends up in an audit. Audits are picked randomly, and the only metric of quality in some queues is whether it's closed or not. This is not a good question - I've voted to close. You did take the right action in this case, even if the weird audit system thinks it disagrees. (There's a lot of hate against the audit system over stuff like this. On the bright side, it catches a post that might have otherwise stayed open for months or even years)

Comment: Also, the question made it to the 'Hot Network Questions', hence the incredible number of upvotes. It was not really a good fit for that either...

Comment: Yes, it is. It does not meet any of the criteria for an off-topic question. It is a practical programming problem, and it's asking about Chromium source code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I do not understand why I failed this audit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303795/i-do-not-understand-why-i-failed-this-audit)

Comment: since [question timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61672829/timeline) shows that it has been in HNQ, this also looks related: [Why are so many useless questions ranked highly, and vice versa?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287163/839601)

Comment: Yeah, I get it, a programmer could figure out what the heck is Chrome doing, but that's only because we have many talented programmers on the site and some of them had an itch to know why. But the answer that OP doesn't know is looking for isn't for "why software behave that way" but "why was the software made to behave that way". Languages like japanese has their own word boundary and a bad implementation could trash the assumptions of a programmer, but the OP didn't phrase its question like that.

Answer (score -1):

Why do we do moderation at all? Well, we try to prevent wrong / misleading information on this site. So in other words: We moderate *answers*. Then why do we close questions at all? Well, bad questions tend to attract bad answers. That's the reason why we (or at least I) close questions. Is this question off-topic (according to the rules that were developed over the years)? Maybe. Are the answers off-topic? No, definitely not. So maybe this is a case where our rules for the general case do not quite work. Is it bad when rules don't quite fit? Yes. Can we improve them? Well, I can't really think of better ones. Maybe we just have to accept that they can't work in every case.