# Do questions by people with high rep get overshadowed by questions from newcomers because it's encouraged to upvote them?

Tags: discussion, questions

[Questions with certain tags with 2 or more upvotes sorted by new](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=[node.js]+or+[socket.io]+or+[jade]+or+[passport]+or+[passport.js]+or+[mongoose]+is:question+answers:0+score:2)

I often see questions with 1-2 upvotes that I wonder why would any one upvote this. I mean, it's a good question as in it's asked in a good way, but you could easily find its duplicate or even a cursory search on google would've answered it. Then I realize it must be upvoted in the review process where it's encouraged to upvote questions asked by newcomers simply for the fact that there's nothing "syntactically" wrong with them. Why is that?

What about questions asked by people who've been around for a while? (not their 1st question) or people with some reps. They ask better questions and yet no one's upvoting those. Mainly because they're and not as much exposed or encouraged to be upvoted.

edit: Not a dupe of [Laziness is rewarded big time by the reputation system](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271985/laziness-is-rewarded-big-time-by-the-reputation-system) My main point was that it's unnecessarily encouraged to upvote first post question just for the sake of "welcoming" them. Now these upvotes are just 1 or 2 but I think it overshadows questions asked by people with already some reps because no one "welcomes" them. As a result they get less attention.

And also, questions asked by new users are *generally* not that great. Exceptions are there but I'm talking generally. 100 people with 1k rep ask more better questions than 100 people with 0 rep. For 10k rep the ratio would be even more skewed.

Besides, because these upvotes are coming from people who are merely reviewing the questions they upvote only based on whether the question "looks good", but to people looking to answer them, they're easily googlable and should not have had received the upvotes. They're not receiving the upvotes based on content of their questions, only their presentation.

Comment: "it's a good question as in it's asked in a good way" - I'd say stop there. I loath the idea of sending people to google, or where ever, to get the answer they're after. Why not just replace SO with a search bar that says "Goggle that ish dumby!" Nearly ***every*** objective question could be answered without SO; I mean we're largely talking about documented tech. So many times I use documentation to answer questions - should those questions be damned because it's answerable elsewhere? Hell, I already can't ask questions cause by the time I get it up to SO's standard I've answered it!

Comment: @Chief Arguably that's exactly what you should be doing. The job of a programmer is to piece the pieces together. If you *can* do it yourself, simply by methodically asking the right questions and looking up the right answers... then you're doing the job of a programmer. If you're just throwing everything at SO, you're merely outsourcing...

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils: However, if people would just google their question's _title_, and look at the first 5 results returned, we could get rid of all of those extremely basic questions that get closed as duplicates.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils: and what if entering the [exact question title](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30488798/2564301) into Google gives the answer right away [and it's on the library's home page](https://www.google.com/search?q=DOMPDF+-+TIF+image+support%3F)...?

Comment: @deceze, well not everyone here is trying to fulfill the "job" of a programmer; it's not a professional programmer only site. There's nothing besides self gratification for enthusiast who spends days finding an answer. Plus, that's arguably *everyone's* "job" by that standard; you could apply it to the entire SE. Which brings me to the point - what good is a Q&A site(s) when so many are pre-occupied with keeping questions from being asked?

Comment: @Cerbrus, I'm struggling to find the usefulness of that comment. If that is true for some subset of questions there's no way to make that happen so it seems like fantasy or really just a true statement. I guess the problem I have is how is a question both "good" and yet a duplicate? It OP thinks the question is good, then I'm saying don't ponder who upvotes questions and why. If it's good then upvote it, if it's a dup flag it. That's the system.

Comment: @Chief Well, it explicitly is a site ***for professional and enthusiast programmers***... All I'm saying is that if you can come to a solution simply by writing it down and thinking it through, then there's no reason to have other people do this for you here. There are more than enough cases where writing it down and thinking it through it *not* sufficient for someone to solve a problem – fair enough, ask a question.

Comment: @deceze, ?? - I said professional only. That was meant to convey that an enthusiast might not need to develop the skills of a pro - isn't that reasonable? You seem to be implying that if you deem a problem solvable by those methods then it's solvable by all people. It's not exactly fair to accept enthusiasts and then hold them to CS/pro standards. And the questions that I can't ask aren't those kinds, the point is I spend 3 days exhausting  avenues and therefore don't get much from the site despite putting a lot into it. It's sort of like a bad relationship.

Comment: @Chief Let's start from the basic premise again: you were complaining that in the process of writing a good SO question, you have solved it yourself. I say: *Great!* If you *can* solve it yourself, then you don't need SO! This goes for enthusiasts the same as for professionals. It's up to you to decide when to give up answering something yourself and ask the community. I never said *everything* that can be solved without SO *must* be solved without SO. I *am* saying that SO shouldn't be your first (and for some apparently *only*) avenue for solutions.

Comment: @Chief *"what good is a Q&A site(s) when so many are pre-occupied with keeping questions from being asked?"* – because many questions are already drowning in the flood and/or must be cleaned up and/or closed. I'm not really trying to target *you* specifically with my comments; rather I'm targeting the masses which constantly post questions which really often do just need a bit more work and they wouldn't need to be asked. If you're investing enough energy into your questions to sometimes be answering them yourself, you're already better than a majority of question posters...

Comment: @deceze, no I wasn't originally complaining. You sort of cherry picked a few words out of larger comment where the much more important point was "nearly ***all***" questions are answerable. I was only saying if we keep trying to make it difficult there's no point. The even larger point that I've said now many times is if OP thinks the question is good - *quit thinking about it* and go on about your day; if it's not use the tools the system provides.

Comment: @deceze, your second comment doesn't answer that question - sorry. You'd have to explain how you think a Q&A site is at *all* valuable if there's no questions to answer. I'm not saying all questions are good or aren't duplicates. And again, my originally comment was brought about the op saying it was a good question. My criteria of a good question is apparently better defined than some in this post. That's about all I can say. We're going around circles of different radii and getting off point.

Comment: BTW everyone. The fact that this post is marked as a dup of **that** is at least part of the point. People apparently went through trying to find a dup when none actually existed or could be found; but that didn't stop them. It appears it's a technique of "at any cost" Why? That happens *all* the time. One person incorrectly thinks it's a dup, or possibly it's *remotely* related, then enough follow to seal its fate.

Comment: @Jongware, What about it? Are you under the impression that I said all questions are good or should be permitted? Where did I say that? Also, you have the rep yet there's no down vote nor close vote. Does that not implicitly comply with its existence? It's clear you were there. Don't we have a responsibility to take the appropriate action on such a question; I mean that's what everyone's all up in arms about...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I sense two slightly different aspects in your question.

#### Exposure

Yes, it seems possible that new users get some additional exposure for their questions in the Triage queue, and may pick up upvotes this way that they might otherwise not get.

If you think that new users getting this advantage over experienced users is unfair, that seems like a valid concern. And purely based on principles, I somewhat agree with it. Posts should get votes completely independent of user rep.

Personally, I'm not overly worried about it. As long as *only good posts* from new users are upvoted in this context, I say: Let them have their additional exposure, upvotes, and corresponding rep. There are plenty of bad questions from new users, and I see no harm in giving the new users who deliver high quality content a bit of a head start, and encouragement. It also helps them reach some basic privileges, like voting and commenting, more quickly. And we want users who have shown the ability to write good posts to have those privileges.

On the other hand, one or two extra upvotes on a question probably doesn't make a big difference to high rep users. As long as the question is high quality, it will probably get attention anyway, and will eventually accumulate upvotes if it deserves them.

#### Upvotes for Mediocre Questions

Now, if you're suggesting that questions get upvoted in the Triage queue even though they do not meet certain quality standards, that would be a different problem. I don't know if that's the case. I have certainly seen mediocre questions that get at least one very quick upvote. But I have no idea if that's an undesirable side effect of the Triage queue, or just a cat walking over somebody's keyboard.

If this is indeed happening, it means that the reviewers are not doing a very good job reviewing. They should only upvote questions that they believe deserve an upvote, independent of the context where they encounter the question. So they should upvote questions in the Triage queue that they would upvote if they saw them during their normal site usage. Otherwise, they shouldn't. IMHO, there should definitely not be a lower standard for voting in any review queue.

Comment: That you can't vote inside of the triage queue, but have to click out of it, suggests to me that placing the blame there is a red herring.

Comment: When 3 Looks Ok are achieved, the system prompts you to upvote good questions @TZHX I think it's what Reto meant.

Comment: @Docteur Frankly, I haven't used the triage queue much. It seems like it's mostly empty. So I was mainly responding based on what I saw in the question, which did seem to suggest new users getting upvotes as part of the review process.

Answer (score 13):

Reputation isn't indicative of a person's ability to ask a good question.  I've seen some 10K+ users ask some seriously terrible questions here, and I've seen a new user ask a **brilliant** one.  Not just that, but people will upvote (or not upvote) a question for any reason you could imagine.

All questions are seen as equal to the system, so there's nothing that would rank a question lower based on rep alone.

Comment: Well said. Votes should be based on the merit of the post.