# Understanding question upvoting without coding effort

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I am trying to understand the logic behind upvoting a (now deleted) question: [Split Semi colon separated values into new rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39159720/split-semi-colon-separated-values-into-new-rows).

While the OP does provide information as to what he/she wants the OP provides no coding effort at all. This indicates to me as not enough effort by the OP to try and solve the problem.

Yet this question got upvoted 3 times before I made 1 downvote.

Am I misunderstanding when a question should be accepted as good without any coding effort shown?

Comment: Indeed a no-effort question. A question doesn't have to show _coding_ effort, but it does have to show effort.

Comment: @S.L.Barth what kind of effort would be considered good then without code? (maybe this is more VBA related but I don't see how a question with VBA can be good without code)

Comment: This particular question should show some code effort. In the more general case, a question could also be good if it shows research effort. For example, something like "I found <link>, which says I should do `foo();` but `foo()` is only available in a higher version".

Comment: BTW I'll admit that maybe I was nitpicking.. but just like zero-effort questions and even spam (!) get upvoted, good questions get downvoted. I suspect that some voters have a knee-jerk reaction to any question without code.

Comment: @S.L.Barth thanks for the answer. post it as an answer?

Comment: Me not necessarily towards questions without code, but I do have a knee-jerk reaction to questions which read like just another homework question. "Here are the requirements, go go go". The resulting code might help multiple people, but the way the question is asked is likely not ever going to allow people to find it.

Comment: @Gimby I totally agree on that. If it's a homework dump, I'll downvote and vote-to-close. Just for the record, I'm talking about homework _dumps_. A student who shows effort, and just needs some help, is fine.

Comment: @DragonSamu I'm not sure my comment really answers the question. I'll see about answering later, but don't hold your breath.

Comment: Every now and then you will simply just see bad questions which are for some strange reason up voted beyond the stray +1 up votes that randomly happen. I tend to just throw the question into the php chat to ensure that I'm not completely wrong with my down vote of the otherwise up voted question.

Comment: two of four upvotes were likely cast by two [users who answered](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/281787/165773) this question. If it additionally got a random upvote from some voting badge hunter with rep less that 125 (who can only vote up) that would make a solid looking 3 and some inexperienced reader may simply decide to jump the bandwagon, newcomers rarely know quality norms and OTOH often see that [Laziness is rewarded big time by the reputation system](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271985/839601)

Comment: Here [another of those](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39167465/how-to-get-hexadecimal-value-from-combined-booleans-in-android-studio). You can probably find another upvoted zero-effort question in 5 minutes :-(

Comment: Only debugging questions explicitly require code to be on topic. Non-debugging questions may be too broad or off-topic for other reasons, but not because they are missing an MCVE. Asking how to do something is perfectly on-topic, so long as it isn't an overly broad request, such as "How do I write an operating system" (yes those actually exist). Showing a lack of research effort is a reason to downvote, but a question showing a lack of research effort does not immediately mean that it must be downvoted into oblivion...

Comment: For many basic questions, showing heaps of research effort is just noise. What I want in a question is a clear, on-topic, narrowly scoped question. That's it. I don't want to hear how the user read the whole internet. I don't want every question on the site to be a debugging question. If it is something that has been asked before, I'll close vote it as a duplicate. If the question has been asked thousands of times and all the user would have to do is type their question title into google, I will downvote, then close vote as a duplicate.

Comment: Some people see SO as a Facebook of programming, where all you can do is Like. A post about programming? That is an interest of mine. Upvote!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

No, you are not misunderstanding anything. If a question shows absolutely no effort on the part of the asker, that is a completely valid reason to downvote. Other valid reasons to downvote include:

- The question is poorly formatted.
- The question is unclear or otherwise difficult to understand.
- The question does not contain sufficient information to understand or reproduce the problem (including sample code, in situations where it is necessary).
- The question is not actually a question, but rather a "task" or "assignment". This includes no-effort homework dumps, "plz send me teh codez", and so on.
- The question is too broad, asks for a recommendation of a library or other off-site resource, has nothing to do with computer programming, or otherwise runs afoul of one of our stated guidelines.
- The answer to the question would not ever be useful to another programmer; the question has some inherent attribute that makes it completely worthless. (Be careful with this, but it *can* be a valid downvote reason, even when it's not a valid reason to close.)
- The question is asking something that is already very clearly answered in the official documentation, or could be trivially answered by looking at the first 2–3 results on Google. (Another variation on the "no effort" problem. Again, be careful with this, but it is a valid and time-honored motivation for downvoting.)

In the first case (poor formatting), it would be appreciated if you took the time to edit the question and fix these formatting problems. In the other cases, you should strongly consider voting to close the question (or, if you don't have close-vote privileges, [flagging it for closure](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts)).

But above all, remember that votes are personal, and you are free to cast them however you see fit (so long as you don't engage in fraud). Therefore, while I and many others will agree with you that question was poor quality and deserved a downvote, clearly there were at least three people who thought it deserved an upvote. They were not "wrong", they just hold a minority opinion.

It is difficult to explain why people vote for obviously poor questions. Perhaps they are the same people who *ask* such obviously poor questions in the first place, and have absolutely no quality standards of their own. Or perhaps they have the same problem and want to see an answer, without really caring about the quality of the question itself. Or maybe they're the type of people who will upvote any damned thing because they want to make Stack Overflow feel more "welcoming". Of course, it's also possible that [Tim Post lost his keys again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215379/should-drive-by-downvoting-be-more-effectively-caught/215397#215397).

Either way, the great thing about the vote system is that the majority consensus will win out. This is why it's so important to *vote* on questions, whether up or down.

Comment: I thought "too broad" and "asks for recommendation" were close reasons, not downvote reasons. Aren't you confusing "not useful" (DV) with "off-topic" (CV)?

Comment: Close reasons and downvote reasons are not mutually exclusive. The majority of the reasons you would close a question are also reasons to downvote it. The only real exception is duplicates; I'd only downvote a duplicate if it was a painfully obvious duplicate where the person didn't even bother to type a few keywords into Google. And no, I'm not confusing "not useful" with "off topic". I said very clearly to *"Be careful with this, but it can be a valid downvote reason, even when it's not a valid reason to close."*

Answer (score 3):

In general it is perfectly fine to have very highly upvoted question even if it shows no research when question is really useful. Also such questions generally happen to gradually collect upvotes, possibly starting negative.

For this particular question it is very unlikely to be first question on the topic - so I have no expectations it will ever collect any positive votes for general usefulness.

Comment: Yes, I regularly upvote questions (even if they show no effort) when they express the same problem that I am researching.

Comment: This. Some questions are put on stack overflow just so that stack overflow has the question and answer.