# Should we vote on feature requests just based on the question itself, or should we take other information into consideration?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, voting, meta, upvotes

Voting is different on meta. People vote on feature requests to express whether they agree or disagree with the proposal, rather than just voting on the clarity or usefulness of the post.

However, sometimes answers or comments on a feature request can persuade us to think differently about a feature request.

E.g.:

> **Request/Proposal:** make questions never get closed or deleted
>
> **User:** that sounds like a great proposal! I hate it when my questions get closed.
>
> **Comment:** there are multiple problems with this proposal. If questions never get closed or deleted, it would allow spammy low-quality content to stay on the site, and we don't want that.
>
> **User:** I see. I guess that wouldn't be so great after all.

Other sources of information, such as answers and comments, can change our minds on how we want to vote (upvote or downvote).

**Should we vote on feature requests just based on the question itself, or it it okay to take other information into consideration?**

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking here. Can you clarify?

Comment: @Pekka웃: _"Should we vote on feature requests just based on the question itself, or it it okay to take other information into consideration?"_

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As per your example:

First, you agree with the proposal: You upvote it.
Then, you read some info, and realize that the proposal is a ***horrible*** idea.

Why on earth would you still keep the proposal upvoted?

In other words: Use common sense. Vote with whatever information's available to you.

---

The OP could easily have missed some crucial information that completely changes how well / poorly a feature request would work. There's no reason to ignore anything outside of the feature request.

Comment: Aren't votes locked after a while?

Comment: As long as the question isn't edited, yes.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should definitely take other information into consideration than just the 'body' of the feature request. Stack Overflow is a [representative democracy](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote). While a positive score for a feature request is by no means a guarantee that it will be implemented, it can be a strong indication of the wishes of the community.

Suppose there is a referendum about a [political issue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Kingdom_European_Union_membership_referendum,_2016), which you have to vote for or against. Do you base your judgement *solely* on the question on the [referendum wording](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Kingdom_European_Union_membership_referendum,_2016#Referendum_wording) and your personal opinion, or do you take into account all discussions and public debates about it? I bet you do – at the very least, subconsciously.

Comment: The Brexit referendum seems a rather poor example. There is little evidence that the majority of voters considered all discussions, public debates, and evidence surrounding the question. Their final decision certainly does not suggest that they did.

Comment: @CodyGray: Glorfindel is not claiming they did(n't). It's just an example explaining you _should_.

Comment: It is hardly worth arguing about, I suppose, but I certainly read the answer as saying that all these considerations were taken into account: *"Do you..., or do you...? I bet you do"* implies that you are doing the second thing.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, there are no "rules" for voting. You can vote however you like.<sup>*</sup>

Second, many of the common reasons to vote on Meta are the same as [the reasons to vote on the main site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/333235/366904), such as the question being off-topic, unconstructive (*i.e.*, a rant without apparent purpose), unclear, poorly formatted, completely lacking in research effort, etc.

[With feature requests in particular, people *also* commonly vote according to whether or not they agree with the feature request](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta). Such votes are not necessarily not a reflection of the quality or acceptability of the question itself, but rather on the merits of the proposal made by the question. And in this special case, you should take *all* evidence into account. If that means you initially agreed with a feature request, but reading a comment or answer changed your mind, voting to express disagreement is a perfectly valid course of action. Or vice versa.

I get the impression that you are trying to make this all far too complicated. There is no reputation on Meta. Voting serves as a strong, yet noiseless, signal of the community's reaction to your proposal. Therefore, vote according to the signal that you wish to send. The process by which you arrive at that conclusion is quite irrelevant.

<sub><sup>*</sup> Assuming you are not engaging in voter fraud or voting based on the name of the user rather than the content of the post. The standard ethics of voting apply. If you didn't already know that, please abstain from voting altogether.</sub>