# Should a feature request be voted based on its priority?

Tags: discussion, voting, meta

If people come to meta to post a feature request, should it be voted taking into account how important it is **compared** to other requests?

The only question I've found that could in any way relate to is [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333942/should-we-vote-on-feature-requests-just-based-on-the-question-itself-or-should), but it's not really the same since mine is how requests should relate to each other.

---

I don't know how to elaborate more on this except with an example. Let's assume these are valid examples, just for the sake of the discussion.

**Feature Request 1:** Add two-factor authentication to login.
Estimated Priority: 6 [Medium]

**Feature Request 2:** Make SO links look like META links (underlined).  <sub>Yes, I find them cool.</sub>
Estimated Priority: 1 [Very-Low]

<sup>Don't forget, we should *pretend* both suggestions are acceptable.</sup>

In this case, should *Feature Request 2* be voted based on its importance **compared to other** feature requests, such as *Feature Request 1*? If so, wouldn't the votes be much more volatile - since the major requests could change from time to time?

Comment: This question is based on [an answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/360014/4577762) left on one of my questions. **I acknowledge its point** and that the request could be considered a minor improvement. If voting, please, do so **based on it's content only**. No rant is needed for this one, as the question _could_ be considered well received, based on vote counts.

Comment: For the experienced: should I tag this as `feature-request`s with `meta` as this is about them? Would it look like a feature request? xD

Comment: The [meta-tag:feature-request] is for requesting features, not for asking questions about requesting features.

Comment: @Servy It's good I didn't, then. ty

Comment: Interesting question, but the voting on feature requests has equivalent-to-zero effect on when and whether they're implemented, so I'm not really sure it matters.

Comment: Yeah, but the question is supposed to look more like a guideline, not only to others, but to myself when voting on them ^^ @JoshCaswell

Comment: Vote accordingly to your own judgment... you know, it's just a vote... on Meta... (not a significant impact)

Comment: Short answer, no. On what basis would you prioritize ? It is your vote that makes it a priority, eventually.

Comment: @AntoinePelletier impact is not important to this question. I'm just asking for guidance as to what should I consider when making a vote decision.

Answer (score 15):

> In this case, should Feature Request 2 be voted based on it's importance compared to other feature requests, such as Feature Request 1? If so, wouldn't the votes be much more volatile -since the major requests could change from time to time-?

This was the problem that the old UserVoice system that predated Meta sites worked: you got a fixed number of votes that you could apply to bugs or feature-requests, and once they were gone the only way to vote on something new was to remove a vote from a suggestion you'd previously expressed a desire to see implemented.

In theory, this was supposed to help prioritize things: if something was ranked #1-#6 (where 6 was the number of outstanding votes), that meant folks *currently* wanted those 6 things more than everything else...

...In practice, most folks don't have time for that sort of strategic voting. And those of us who did... Well, we may have found it easier to just create sockpuppet accounts than to tediously prune our past wish-lists every time there was a new suggestion with some merit. Or perhaps even worse, spend our time vehemently bashing other popular requests to try and discourage others from voting for them. In short, the goal was noble but the actual consequences were not great.

Meta doesn't work that way. Your votes are effectively limited only by the number of days you care to show up here and use them. So you can *and usually should* **upvote every proposal you think has merit: the ultimate ranking will be determined by the number of people who feel the same as you do**, *not* the aggregate weights of each individual's priorities.

*That said...* there's a caveat: your time is still precious. You're under no obligation to consider every feature request, and if you feel a given proposal is frivolous and stands to waste your energy and that of other readers like you simply by existing... Then you may wish to downvote it. There are endless [color of the bikeshed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_triviality) proposals that threaten to siphon off the attention of folks who would otherwise be able to express useful opinions on areas where they have a vested interest - if you find these are becoming personally overwhelming, then indicate that. [Especially if they lack freehand circles](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/bug/info).

Comment: I'm upvoting this because I liked the way you presented your opinion -which is different from the one I had when posting the question- in the last couple paragraphs.

Comment: I just find it weird that (let's call) a to-do list have items 'removed' (downvotes) based on the items already there. Specially since finishing the important ones won't bring back the others (votes on low-priority won't change after implementation of high-priority). But I guess that, since votes would mean such priority, you can only try _to do_ some of the things, being important to choose wisely, not allowing less important items to go up the list. I can understand it.

Comment: That's the ultimate truth here: priority is determined by devs and PMs, not votes. Votes help visibility, but ultimately someone still has to make a call as to whether they're gonna build or fix something; doing that purely on voting is stupid, since the bikeshed "we need more pluralization logic" stuff will always win out over, say, a bug that makes the site completely unusable for Mac users. Mac users are people too; they may've made some bad choices, but they should still be able to read Q&A sites.

Comment: That's my original idea as to why we shouldn't base the vote on other requests, because we are actually not the ones choosing which to implement. Now I'm just meh. I've let go, I guess.

Answer (score 10):

You should be voting based on the usefulness of a post, just like you always do when voting on any post.

Naturally the opportunity cost of any potential feature is something you need to consider when evaluating its usefulness.  If there are far better things to be spending time on, then that's not a useful feature to implement, and you should reflect that in your vote.

Comment: Tbh, this asnwer still doesn't shed much light into the subject for me. You start with _"You should be voting based on the usefulness of a post"_ and then you say _"If there are far better things [...] that's not a useful feature_. Almost contradictory.

Comment: @FirstOne How is it contradictory?

Comment: I can see what you meant - correct me if I'm wrong - that a feature is only useful if compared to other features, so, voting based on usefulness includes how it compares to other features. But I don't think that's how we should define _useful_. It could be a wording or interpretation problem (English is my second language), but useful is something `being of use or service; serving some purpose; advantageous`. I'm sure that one thing serving a purpose prevents another from serving its own.

Comment: One thing I'd like to mention is: what happens when the useful features start being implemented? Are the votes on the other _not-so-useful_ requests going to be revised to fit the new reality?

Comment: @FirstOne If I offer you a service where you pay me $10 and I give you $5 is my service useful to you?  "I'm giving you $5, of course it's useful, because there's a benefit."  No, of course not.  You need to consider the *net* benefit/usefulness of any choice, rather than considering the benefits devoid of the costs.  The costs of implementing any feature include the opportunity costs, which are very often very significant.  You can't just ignore those (or other) costs and only look at the possible benefits of the prospective feature.

Comment: To be noted: I missed a **not** in `I'm sure that one thing serving...` It should be `I'm **not** sure one thing...`. Right now it's seems arrogant :\

Comment: I can completely understand the point and I kinda agree with it. But I don't know. It seems wrong in this context. I don't see the cost of implementation as a factor to analyse feature-requests since the choice of implementation is not made by us - the people voting. We don't control requests priorities nor do we always have knowledge of other still unimplemented requests. That makes the voting ambiguous and volatile - not to mention priority itself being subjective from one voter to another.

Comment: @FirstOne If you're ignoring the costs, then you're not accurately analyzing how beneficial the prospective feature is.  The cost has an *enormous* effect on how useful the potential feature actually is.  If you ignore costs then you'll (incorrectly) conclude that enormous changes that would take lots of time and effort but produce mediocre benefits are useful features, while features that are super quick and easy but only have a bit of an upside aren't worth doing.  The opposite is the reality.  Of course votes are subjective, they're subjective even if you do ignore costs.

Comment: I guess what I'm trying to say is: that specific cost should be taken into account by the people picking the requests to be actually implemented, not by people voting on them.

Comment: @FirstOne Why do you think the people voting on the features shouldn't be voting on how useful the features would actually be?

Comment: I don't think I said they _shouldn't be voting on how useful the features would actually be_. I'm just saying we shouldn't consider useful-ness a relative-to-others aspect and shouldn't base it on priorities since these tend to change. (If I said "useful", I probably mixed up the words and most likely I meant "priority")

Comment: @FirstOne You're specifically saying that we should ignore the costs associated with implementing a feature, and since the costs associated with a feature *dramatically* impact its usefulness, you're saying that we shouldn't be voting based on it's usefulness.  If you're voting based on its usefulness, then you are, by definition, considering all associated costs, including opportunity costs.  If you want to vote on a post based on something other than it's usefulness then I (or anyone else) can't stop you, but you're doing so contrary to the site's guidelines on how votes should be used.

Answer (score 3):

You can vote however you like.  The only guidance is to upvote "useful" posts/feature-requests and downvote unhelpful ones.  That's up to personal taste, but like Servy mentions, opportunity costs and returns on investment are possible metrics you can use in your judgement of "usefulness."  So feel free to vote more eagerly for "high priority" issues.

Priority manifests itself somewhat organically via the score of meta posts.  If a bunch of users all think a feature is important, they'll upvote it.  Your single vote is part of the large community judgement of "priority" for a potential feature.

However, this completely misses the point.  Community managers/SO developers can use community input to help guide their decisions, but they ultimately set their own agenda.  The community provides a list of suggestions, and Stack Exchange does whatever they want.  Highly upvoted feature requests are more likely to end up in their company discussions, but that's the extent on the community's influence on prioritizing new features.

Answer (score -4):

I don't agree with voting on the quality/importance of a feature request based on its relative worth versus other active feature requests.

Could we not have a dedicated page for all approved feature requests which has the same look and function as an election page?

The SE staff can create, update, delete any features as they are approved, changed, and rolled out over time.  The page would allow users to execute preferential voting on all viable features and the "election" would never close/end.

Like elections, anyone with over 150 rep can vote on the priorities of all available features.  This way SE staff can check the pulse of the community if/when they wish.  If there is a concern about voter preferences becoming stale, then close the feature prioritizing page annually and let everyone vote on a clean slate every January (a reboot).

To tie up any loose ends regarding the correlation between elections and feature preferencing, the feature requests are the "candidates", the vote tallies and tags will be presented in the "candidate score card", and the explanation of the feature would be the nomination/elevator pitch of the candidate.

I see the election model as perfectly suitable for use with the pool of active feature requests.

Comment: Well, the company is always going to decide how to prioritize any status-planned feature requests relative to their other work. I'm not sure they would find it useful to separate the popularity of a request from how soon we want it. And from the community's side I think people would find it frustrating that the priority vote would have no affect on how fast things happen.

Comment: Adding more process to a process that is already painstakingly slow isn't going to speed up the process.

Comment: This proposed feature doesn't attempt to speed up any processes -- they will take as long as they take.  The goal here is to give the community a tool which allows clear communication about the priority of approved requests.  This seems more ideal than having the community give a cloudy indication of what they favor based on a binary up/down vote on a new proposal.