# Should we make the pop-up not appear when downvoted [feature-request] question on meta?

Tags: feature-request, downvotes, meta, user-interface

On [What is "meta"? How does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta):

> On posts tagged [feature-request], voting indicates agreement or
> disagreement with the proposed change rather than just the quality or
> usefulness of the post itself.

But when I downvoted a question with the tag [feature-request], this pop-up appeared:

[image]

I think that we should hide this, or change the text to something like:

> Please consider adding a comment and/or an answer to show your disagreement with the
> proposed change

Should we change this?

Comment: But voting on feature requests can also indicate the quality, especially if the feature request is still unclear (nothing to agree/disagree with since there's no proposal to be evaluated yet).

Comment: @AndrewT. That's right. But the downvote can also be disargeement. That's why I also suggest to hide the pop-up altogether.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Let's hide it everywhere! The system should not be implying any connection between votes and comments.

Comment: On the other hand, no comment downvotes are one of the least constructive forms of feedback in Stack Exchange and are often perceived as a faceless attack which can trigger "why the dv?" comments from the OP.  People crave understanding when others disagree.  Clear communication aids true understanding.

Comment: @mickmackusa they also perceive it as an attack when a comment explains how an answer is not correct. Or that it doesn't answer the question. Or that it shouldn't be suggested for any other reason. The only winning move is not to play but...that's already one of the failure states. There is no winning move.

Comment: @mickmackusa That people perceive downvotes as an attack is an educational problem: they are seen as a weapon, and in turn they weaponize them, leading to a vicious circle. Yes, I understand you feel strongly about this. Likewise, there are people who feel strongly about their right to participate in the site without facing any backlash.

Comment: No comment downvotes do nothing to help me understand what is flawed/unsavory about my post.  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/413195/2943403 This is easily the #1 thing that I hate about Meta.

Comment: Downvotes are not meant as a signal to you as the author. They are not intended to help the author understand anything.

Comment: That seems nonsensical to me then. Or a wasted opportunity.

Comment: @CodyGray, Surely a downvote should be a signal that something's not right. In Meta - disagreement. On the main site -  *shrug*, God only knows, could be anything.

Comment: @ouflak It's a signal to everyone seeing the post. It was not designed to give feedback to its author. That is done through comments, which are a separate mechanism.

Comment: While DVs may not be _intended_ as a signal to the author, the fact that downvotes on posts cost the post author reputation basically _guarantees_ that DVs will be interpreted this way to some degree. I'm not saying we abolish that penalty, but it feels a bit rough to argue that authors shouldn't consider DVs a signal when they experience a direct penalty from them (at least on main). If the answer to that is simply "don't care too much about reputation", then that's fine, but this is at least a little more complicated a problem than just "people who complain about downvotes don't get it".

Comment: It really isn't. You're coupling two mechanisms that have no association with one another. Reputation measures the net value of your contributions to this site, in terms of questions and answers. If your content receives downvotes, then it's not considered by the system to be high-quality content, and thus your reputation is correspondingly reduced. That doesn't mean that the votes are meant to be a signal to you directly. In fact, they are a signal to *the system* and future viewers that the content is not useful or not interesting. @zcoop98