# Users with only one question/answer shouldn't get all privileges

Tags: discussion, new-users

There are some users, that only answered one question that got really popular, but never logged in again.

Those users shouldnt get the same priviledges others would get with lots of activity

Comment: But if they never log in again, why does it matter? Furthermore, this user in particular is unregistered, the chances of that person being able to access their account again are practically zero.

Comment: They could come back and cause havoc.

Comment: So posting a single good answer once is a bad thing, but a huge amount of unspecified activity is always good? There is at least one young user with >10k rep in the python tag who got there with drive-by answers to low-hanging fruit / off-topic questions, and has demonstrated repeatedly that he has no idea of any advanced topics (e.g. recommending "just use print+join" instead of curses for the question "how to redraw a part of the terminal"). If we discriminate based on the amount of activity, we must surely also discriminate on the _type_ of activity, right? See where that would lead to?

Comment: What @l4mpi says. This wouldn't solve the problem - to the extent that there *is* a problem.

Comment: @rubo77: no, because as BoltClock already told you that specific account is unregistered. Only if the person was ever able to recover the cookie stored in their browser *45 months ago* will they be able to log in and use their privileges.

Comment: [Life isn't fair](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271017/839601)

Comment: LOL! Didn't know about the possibility of posting unregistered. So let's continue talk about only registered users.

Comment: Just for fun: http://stackoverflow.com/users/268413/lfx-cool

Answer (score 9):

1. The user that posted a single question/answer effectively has no priviledges because as you have written, he's not using SO anymore, so no damage made
2. Such cases are very rare, so the probability that someone who have gain many priviledges by single, 'golden shoot' may misues them is very low
3. If someone is misusing their priviledges, the moderators can lock them, so there's no need to implement a special exception for such a case

Answer (score 1):

SO is about quality, not quantity. If someone contributes good content, and doesn't break any rules, it's a good thing. They have earned their reputation and privileges.

If you find any genuine case of abuse of privileges by a user, please raise a flag so that moderators can look into it. The number of posts written by a user are not a factor while reporting abusive users.

However, please avoid calling out users on Meta when they haven't done any harm and their only visible activity is contributing high-quality content to make the internet a better place.

Comment: Why shouldn't the public profile be linked? I didn't "call out" anything bad about that user. And sure, the user did a high-quality golden-shot-answer ;)

Comment: because this can be discussed without Alex's profile. Linking profile sometimes results in invoking the meta-effect upon the user and post, so better avoid it @rubo77 :)

Comment: OK, I will keep this in mind