# Vote system favors easy questions

Tags: discussion, voting

I have observed, that the number of votes on an answer often is reciprocal to the research effort and competence needed to answer it. This has the following reasons:

- Questions on a broad subject, where many people have detailed knowledge about, get many visits and therefore many upvotes.
- The more trivial a question (and its answer) is, the more people feel competent to deem it correct and upvote.

Conversely:

- Questions on a very narrow topic are not read and/or understood by many people at all.
- When the answerer had to put a lot of (research) effort in his post, it sometimes is tedious to follow and many people might be deterred from comprehending (or even reading) it.

I think, it would be desirable to have a correcting factor here to motivate more people to tackle difficult questions, but I have to admit, that I do not have a good proposal for a solution.

Any comments?

Edit: The proposed duplicate is very different: It focuses on questions, while here I wanted to discuss a mechanism, on how to motivate people better to put effort into answering difficult, specialized questions without having the feeling that noone takes notice of that.

Edit2: I still do not see where the linked question is a duplicate. The focus is obviously completely different. While the linked question asks to minimize "bad questions", this discusses how to maximize the effort for good answers on difficult questions.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297853/are-we-too-preoccupied-with-easy-questions

Comment: You can also read about [the bikeshed problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31253/the-bikeshed-problem-and-stack-exchange) on the Overmeta.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Yes, exactly ;) Didn't find that in my research. Unfortunately, no good proposals there, too...

Comment: What exactly is wrong with the current system? The... easier questions are the ones that will appeal to the most users, and the difficult ones are the ones that will appeal to the least. When i say users, i mean both answerers and other users who have the same question. By that logic, i see nothing wrong with the easier questions being better rewarded; they're simply more useful to the community.

Comment: It is a self-correcting problem, there is (almost) no user that doesn't get bored with answering trite questions.  They typically last for ~3 months and then completely burn out and never come back.  Answering difficult questions is a much more rewarding experience, it isn't just the OP that benefits from it.  You learn from it yourself and that never gets old.

Comment: Unfortunately, like rabbits, the bad users breed faster than they die off.  We need some kind of anti-vamp virus to thin the population.

Comment: @Martin, you seem to be taking this way too personally. May I suggest you watch an episode of *The Walking Dead* or two to compensate?

Comment: This problem has been much talked about on Meta pretty much from the start more than six years ago. However, I notice that the top 20-30 of users still seems to consist mostly of users who didn't get "big" answering trivial questions (although I know a couple in the 50k-80k range). The system is doing *something* right

Comment: @Pekka웃 The system is ok, which doesn't mean, that it can't be improved. The conservative "We can live with that" attitude just chokes off any progress. This is also a reason for the demise of organizations when they get too big and immobile.

Comment: `The conservative "We can live with that" attitude just chokes off any progress.` I don't think that's the issue here. As said, this has been discussed (and alternatives suggested) from the very start, back when the site had a couple thousand users and was extremely mobile. It's just that no one so far has managed to come up with a concrete suggestion that is better (or that the site owners have deemed worth implementing).

Comment: *how to motivate people better to put effort into answering difficult, specialized questions* - Bounties?

Comment: @Pekka웃 Since we do not know how good it _can_ be, isn't it impossible to determine how big this issue is? Fact is, that many of the more specialized questions remain unanswered (or at least without a sophisticated answer). This is what the site should strive to change I think.

Comment: @BSMP Yes, bounties is a step in the right direction, but a bit too narrow. It is mere a mechanism for the desperate asker than a general solution for this effect.

Comment: `This is what the site should strive to change I think.`  Sure, that would be great. It's come up before, but as said so far no one has managed to make a successful suggestion. If you have something in mind, make a concrete suggestion - but be prepared for it to be analyzed and criticized in minute detail by many experienced users - that is the Meta process all our suggestions have to go through.

Comment: @Pekka웃 First, I would like to see if it is really seen as a problem or if I have a different understanding of this site. For example, KevinB has the opinion, that it is exactly as it should be. If that is the consense of the majority, then all proposals are of course mood.

Comment: *Questions on a very narrow topic are not read and/or understood by many people at all.* The only way to fix that is to attract more experts on that topic to the site. Not sure there's a blanket fix for that one. I'd argue that this, *it sometimes is tedious to follow*, is usually the OP's fault. We want people to show research but that doesn't mean we need a detailed explanation of the OP's thought process at each step. Difficult and specialized don't necessarily have to mean verbose.

Comment: @BSMP Agreed, not necessarily, but nevertheless they often are. If every topic could be explained in a way which was easy to comprehend, the level of education would be much higher than it is.

Comment: I have yet to see a "hard" question that was actually hard, rather than just being a lot of work due to the asker not being willing or capable to do the proper research/debugging before asking. We're programming after all, most problems boil down to a simple flaw in logic or syntax errors. Logic problems can be difficult, but they're only difficult until you break it down into smaller parts and identify where it originates, which again boils down to debugging!

Comment: For the record, I realize I'm being very hypocritical by criticizing others for being too wordy.

Comment: @KevinB - There was that one guy who had a question related to PhD level research. He kept asking for the ability to have monetary bounties. Edit: Nevermind, IIRC that question had a score of 11 so he wasn't hurting for votes even though he never got an answer.

Comment: @HansPassant I have thought about this and I agree on what you observe, but I disagree on your conclusion: The fact, that enthusiastic users "burn out" because they are encouraged to answer a lot of trivial questions shows, that the site sets wrong incentives. That a lot of other people behave otherwise doesn't contradict that. Like everywhere: It is an art to push the people in the right direction, which would otherwise go astray.

Comment: Hmya, those users are dancing to puppet masters like Clay Shirky and Jay Hanlon, people that specialize in knowing how to push geek buttons.  Those users will spend *hours* of their free time getting a scrap of HTML that looks like a badge.  Kinda important that you see the strings yourself, it is a very taboo subject.

Comment: @HansPassant I am sorry, but your response is incomprehensible to me. Could you rephrase that?

Comment: more accurate duplicate is [Laziness is rewarded big time by the reputation system](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/272046/839601)

Comment: @gnat But it's exactly the other way round. The main issue are not others gaining much reward for few effort, but the answers on difficult topics without any votes and comments.

Comment: [Life isn't fair](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271017/why-newbie-questions-bring-so-many-reputation-points-to-the-author)

Comment: @gnat It's got _nothing_ to do with fairness, you have to take a much more pragmatic point of view. Is it ok for the majority of users that answers for trivial questions dominate while the difficult ones starve? It's like in every society: if hard work isn't appreciated, it will work somehow, too. But it will never develop its full potential.

Answer (score -7):

I am afraid i also agree, i believe the favoring comes from having to answer fast questions before OP accepts an answer just because it comes first, additionally a big portion of users just want an answer not an explanation, which degrades the overall quality of stackoverflow.

## Suggestion

**Locking upvotes and accepting answers for the first 5 minutes of posting a question**, this way users have much more time to provide a quality answer, instead of the current way of doing things over three iterations:

1. answer the question as fast as possible
2. edit answer to explain the answer
3. write an example / enhance code written

Comment: I agree with your eyeball assessment that a large portion of users "just" want the answer (aka "send me the codez") and that it's detrimental to SO's quality and reputation, but how would your suggestion help? By the way, I don't think you are answering the question.

Comment: @RadLexus true i did not intend to answer, but more like sharing what i had in mind after reading OP's concern.

Comment: It's crazy how useful to many questions/answers get more upvotes than those that are only useful to a few. /s

Comment: Doesn't this already exist? I think you have to wait several hours before you can accept an answer.

Answer (score -10):

I completely agree. Questions showing no effort whatsoever to even read the basics (e.g. "How to print a string in Java?") get thousands of upvotes, granting the new user who asked it a lot of privileges in few days.

My proposal is to limit the reputation you can get from one question and one answer.

This way you won't be able to become a Superman by asking/answering elementary question while the popular question still gets its upvotes.

This has some advantages:

- Safety: random users don't get a high reputation gain from few questions
- Higher activity: users are motivated to answer more questions well, not to hunt for the easiest ones.

Comment: There is absolutely nothing wrong with rewarding someone with reputation for a phenomenal answer.  [Branch prediction](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11227902/1079354) remains one of the most venerable answers on this site, and it would be a pity if that was cut off.

Comment: I'm on an ipad right now and am too lazy to look up the related stats and discussion, but this has been talked about before. Bottom line: people gaining lots of rep from one trivial answer happens much more rarely that you would think, and thanks to the daily rep cap the amount of rep you can make from an answer is very limited already. 200 upvotes is unlikely to translate to 2000 points. Instating a per-post cap would actually favour the highest rep users the most and take away points from low to moderate rep users

Comment: @Pekka웃:  In the answerer's defense, this particular *question* was from February of this year...

Comment: @Makoto I don't suggest to cancel bounties. They are usually given for hard questions that nobody could answer within few days and ther is no problem with that. The OP talks about easy questions, giving an author same reputation gain, as the answer you call phenomenal.

Comment: Bounties are *definitely* not the thing that have contributed to the score of that question.  The user has maxed out in terms of rep on that question *alone*, but at @Pekka웃 said, this is a rarer occurrence than anything else.  I mentioned that answer because you said to limit the reputation for a question or answer, and my counterargument was that this would apply to *all* questions and answers.  Determining if a question is "easy" can be quite difficult, since it depends on who's asking and who's looking.

Comment: @Makoto Yes, I suggest it for all questions without determining whether they are easy. Reputation is already limited per day, why not limiting it per question? I see the advantages of it. Better safety wrt moderation and higher activity as it motivates to answer more questions.

Comment: @Pekka, could you elaborate more on why having a per-post reputation limit (cap?) is worse than the current system?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136059/revisiting-the-rep-cap-yes-again, read the accepted answer

Comment: @Pekka웃 Interesting discussion, but the only disadvantage I saw in the accepted answer is that users will get less reputation, but this is the intention behind it!

Comment: I'm not finding much posts that get a user to moderator level (assuming 3K, to be that level) within a couple of days: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/580446 and the few that do doesn't seem to be answers to basic questions.

Comment: @rene It is like instead of wearing a safety belt saying: "Nevermind, only 1 in 1000 cars gets into an accident".

Comment: @Noidea the much more important takeaway is this: `A total of 4,843 users have at least one post that has earned them >= 500 rep.` A number as low as this, on a site with several million users, is a strong suggestion that perhaps the problem of users gaining tons of reputation with a trivial answer isn't as widespread as you think in the first place. Can you point to some actual examples where this is a problem?

Comment: Also note that this isn't a bad answer. It's downvoted because [people disagree with you](//stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta).

Comment: @dorukayhan well, thanks for pointing that out, I didn't think one would do that.  Oh, yes, I expected that many people will disagree, because they don't want to lose their source of cheap reputation.

Comment: Consider the possibility that people disagree with you because, you know, you're *wrong.* Especially given that the system is very unlikely to change no matter whether this gets upvoted or not. Again, can you point to an actual example of where this is an actual problem?

Comment: @Pekka, I don't mean necessarily highest moderator privileges with 3K votes. Already the ability to downvote you get with somehting like 100+  or view the review queries with smth like 200+. And it gradually goes like this between 0 and 3K.

Comment: So someone maybe reaches the downvote privilege by answering a trivial question and gaining 13 upvotes (which is very unlikely) instead of answering 13 trivial questions and getting an upvote each. Not sure either is a real problem. A point system will always favour trivial questions; that's a given and has been clear from when the site started in '08. That it still works halfway ok after 8 years, and its top users are still mostly real experts and not just point-gamers, continues to be a huge surprise to me. It's proof that it's no good imagineering problems that may or may not exist, though.

Comment: @Pekka웃 I am not "making" this problem, I am answering the question the user Ctx asks.

Comment: Ctx' question was about the general flaws of the system we have, which are well known. Your answer says "people are gaining huge amounts of points by answering trivial questions and becoming moderators within days." So far I have yet to see you prove that any of that is actually true and not just made up.

Comment: What makes you think that a user who gets a bunch of reputation from a single post is an active user?  And that they would actually do the site any harm from misusing privileges?

Comment: @Pekka웃 I don't mean the moderator, which are elected now as we see. But simple privileges you start get already with 125 reputation points and continue getting as the votes grow.

Comment: @ryanyuyu No, I don't think a user who gets a bunch of reputation from a single post is an active user. Why do you ask?

Comment: If you want to be taken seriously, show some real-world examples of this

Comment: @Pekka웃 Khm, what? There over 20 posts on meta on that problem including this one, which attracted many voted and I am not one of the authors of them!

Comment: Lol. People claiming there is an issue != proof that there is an issue

Comment: @Pekka웃 I presume you're asking about Stack Overflow, but examples of mod powers from a single answer are easy enough to find on scifi.SE. [This guy](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/28603/kyle-hale) has 6k rep from a single answer. I don't think people should get close-vote powers by writing a single answer and then waiting.

Comment: @yellowantphil yeah, that is crazy - and not unlike a couple of answers from the very early days of Stack Overflow. Still think it's an outlier and not a widespread problem in a mature community. See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136059/revisiting-the-rep-cap-yes-again)  this was suggested (by Jon Skeet, our top user, no less!) and rejected because it would mainly hurt lower rep users, and because the problem doesn't seem that huge quantity wise. I wouldn't mind seeing a per-post cap rather than a daily cap, but it likely wouldn't fix anything in terms of...

Comment: ...people answering trivial crap. Someone looking to game rep from trivial answers will just post 10 trivial answers instead of 1 - *which already is likely to be the winning strategy anyway*

Comment: @Pekka웃 I agree with the policy, that one cannot downvote straight away, cannot add comment straight away, can't review straight away, etc. The more influence a privilege has, the higher should be the reputation. Now, there is a workaround, which allows to get reputation very easily. This reduces the effect of the above policy. And I don't like it, because I think the above policy make a lot of sense.

Comment: `Now, there is a workaround, which allows to get reputation very easily` I very seriously doubt that is still the case. Gaining 10-15 points for a trivial answer is no longer the norm, if it ever was. And even if it were, and the reputation gain were capped - *then the user will just post x more trivial answers and gain the same reputation*. How would that fix anything?

Comment: @Pekka웃 Yes, but for that one needs to anser 10 trivial questions instead of just 1, which is great! User is answering more questions. And he shows more positive activity, which is what is needed for him to be trusted. Also, he has to get the upvotes for all 10 answers, but that is not nearly as easy as for 1. For easy questions, people will post answers very quickly, and many people can do it.

Comment: @Pekka웃 by 10-15 points do you mean 10-15 upvotes?

Comment: @Noidea yes, upvotes.

Comment: @Pekka웃 now, about actual problems you need to ask moderators. Seeing the amount of complaints on meta as well as the questions asked now at moderator elections, one can understand that there are a lot of problems. Now, since I am not a moderator on this site, I cannot see whether people, who got high reputation the easy way, actually downvoted useful answers, closed good questions or even banned normal users. I obviously don't have right access to any of this information, so it is wrong to ask me about it. But I see that one can abuse the system.

Comment: @Pekka웃 However, what I can see on this site is downvoting useful answers,  discouraging new users, elementary questions answered by people with huge reputation (whist anybody could answer them), a lot of questions left unanswered, because the users are on the hunt for the easy ones.