# More reputation for easy answers

Tags: discussion

I have been (passively) using the site for a while; only recently I am more actively participating in Q and A. As somone rather new to the question/answer/votaing process I have noticed that quick answers to easy questions tend to be yielding a bigger reward in reputation, because they receive more upvotes than long answers to difficult questions that require a lot of expertise to solve.

I know that there are also examples for the opposite, but that is the impression I got from my own questions and replies. If you think about it, it makes also sense that is like this, because for short and easy Q and As there will be more people who will take the time to read them and there will be more people who will understand them than rather expert issues. And users tend to upvote Q and As that they understand better.

Don't get me wrong, I'm not complaining about the current system. I personally don't care about my reputation; I don't use the site for that reason. But what is your opinion, should there be a system that mitigates this fact? I'm not even saying to reward more reputation for difficult questions to answer (even though this would be indeed a solution, but probably difficult to implement fairly), but maybe you can display those Q and As in a more prominent position.

Comment: The challenge is deciding what is "easy" and what is "hard".  Easy for someone with no knowledge of a language is a lot different than "easy" for an expert.

Comment: Didn't we have a similar discussion a few days ago?

Comment: @Stijn yup (although I think that was an older discussion that received a new answer)

Comment: @Pekka웃 Ah yeah, explains why I didn't find it by browsing through the questions. [Vote system favors easy questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317198/vote-system-favors-easy-questions)

Answer (score 4):

This is a well-known flaw in the system.

So far, as far as I know, no one has come up with a solution that has been both universally welcomed and seriously considered by the team.

If you want to take a shot at changing it, you should suggest something specific; discussion about the general fact of this we've had a lot over the years, the oldest spanning back to 2008 or so.

Don't hold your breath any radical suggestion will ever be implemented, though. There must be a lot of "if in doubt, do not change the secret recipe" sentiment at Stack Overflow - understandably so, given the tremendous success of the site.

Perhaps it's a "capitalism is the worst system ever, except for all the others" kind of situation.

It can't be *that* terrible a flaw, though: the top ranks of users reputation-wise seem to have a vast majority of people who really know what they're talking about (rather than people who gamed their way to the top by answering trivial questions).